# TypeScript: Object.keys return string[]

Tags: typescript

When using `Object.keys(obj)`, the return value is a `string[]`, whereas I want a `(keyof obj)[]`.

```
const v = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
}

Object.keys(v).reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    accumulator.push(v[current]);
    return accumulator;
}, []);
```

I have the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{ a: number; b: number; }' has no index signature.

TypeScript 3.1 with `strict: true`. Playground: [here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20v%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AObject.keys(v).reduce((accumulator%2C%20current)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20accumulator.push(v%5Bcurrent%5D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20accumulator%3B%0D%0A%7D%2C%20%5B%5D)%3B%0D%0A), please check all checkboxes in `Options` to activate `strict: true`.

Comment: Don't think you can do better then a type assertion `(Object.keys(v) as Array<keyof typeof v>)` the definition is what it is

Comment: I think using my `object-typed` package is definition cleaner than doing this type assertion everywhere: `ObjectTyped.keys(v)`. Just `npm i object-typed` and then import it.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns a `string[]`. This is by design as described in this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870)

> This is intentional. Types in TS are open ended. So keysof will likely be less than all properties you would get at runtime.

There are several solution, the simplest one is to just use a type assertion:

```
const v = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

var values = (Object.keys(v) as Array<keyof typeof v>).reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    accumulator.push(v[current]);
    return accumulator;
}, [] as (typeof v[keyof typeof v])[]);
```

You can also create an alias for `keys` in `Object` that will return the type you want:

```
export const v = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

declare global {
    interface ObjectConstructor {
        typedKeys<T>(obj: T): Array<keyof T>
    }
}
Object.typedKeys = Object.keys as any

var values = Object.typedKeys(v).reduce((accumulator, current) => {
    accumulator.push(v[current]);
    return accumulator;
}, [] as (typeof v[keyof typeof v])[]);
```

Comment: Could you explain me why "So keysof will likely be less than all properties you would get at runtime." ?

Comment: @user2010955 that is a quote from the GitHub thread, My understanding of it is that since you can add more properties to any object to JS, the `keyof` operator will not return the same things as `Objects.keys`

Comment: There's also [this quote from Anders](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208) which shows their thinking process.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the link . Just curios did you stumble upon this old answer, suing SO search I rarely find my own answers 

Comment: [Before extending `Object` with `typedKeys` (or anything you don't own), please take some time to read the pros and cons.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14034180/1218980)

Comment: this answer is gold, you can use the same technique to cast the currentValue as enum

Comment: As @EmileBergeron pointed out, you might consider defining your own local function rather than extending the native properties of `Object`. For example: `function getTypedKeys<T>(obj: T): Array<keyof T> { return Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>; }`. Then, where you would normally write `Object.keys(obj)`, you instead write `getTypedKeys(obj)`.

Comment: Would people mind upvoting how you are handling this problem today? (comment with anymore I'm missing)

Comment: 1. inline assertions everywhere: `Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>`

Comment: 2. import `getTypedKeys` wrapper everywhere

Comment: 3. Global `window.getTypedKeys` wrapper

Comment: 4. Global `Object.typedKeys = Object.keys` alias

Answer (score 139):

### Based on Titian Cernicova-Dragomir answer and comment

Use type assertion only if you know that your object doesn't have extra properties (such is the case for an object literal but not an object parameter).

**Explicit assertion**

```
Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>
```

**Hidden assertion**

```
const getKeys = Object.keys as <T extends object>(obj: T) => Array<keyof T>
```

Use `getKeys` instead of `Object.keys`. `getKeys` is a ref to `Object.keys`, but the return is typed literally.

#### Discussions

> One of TypeScript’s core principles is that type checking focuses on the shape that values have. ([reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html))

```
interface SimpleObject {
   a: string 
   b: string 
}

const x = {
   a: "article", 
   b: "bridge",
   c: "Camel" 
}
```

`x` qualifies as a `SimpleObject` because it has it's shape. This means that when we see a `SimpleObject`, we know that it has properties `a` and `b`, but it might have additional properties as well.

```
const someFunction = (obj: SimpleObject) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((k)=>{
        ....
    })
}

someFunction(x)
```

Let's see what would happen if by default we would type Object.keys as desired by the OP "literally":

We would get that `typeof k` is `"a"|"b"`. When iterating the actual values would be `a`, `b`, `c`. Typescript protects us from such an error by typing k as a string.

Type assertion is exactly for such cases - when the programmer has additional knowledge. if you know that `obj` doesn't have extra properties you can use literal type assertion.

Comment: Should be selected answer!

Comment: This was actual very clear and concise ...thank you.

Comment: @DevinGRhode, both solutions do the same, and are both legit. The difference is that getKeys hides assertion from the user. Therefor it creates an easier to use tool. The only thing is you might not expect the only functionality of a function to be type assertion which is why I lean towards the more explicit solution.

Comment: @DevinGRhode, Do you mean I should move my solution above the discussion?

Comment: @DevinGRhode, I value your feedback. I edited my answer per your suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I've actually been finding this thread to be a pretty great reference. I really only learn+remember things when I actually have a need for them. To that end, I think you could probably be using `Extract` as seen in this other answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string#comment114640978_56133795 But, I could be wrong, I'm curious to know what you think

Comment: @DevinGRhode, 1) Inserting that code to my TS environment (TS 4.0.3) I get a TS error (`Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c"'`). 2) `keyof typeof obj` is typed litterally correctly. extracting only strings will be wrong if there is a key which is a number, or a symbol. 3) By asserting Object.keys() return immediately you account for any use cases then just using it in a forEach iterator.

Comment: @DevinGRhode, does it make sense?

Comment: Well, in a large number of cases, you may be able to assert that you are just going to be getting strings. I guess, you could typecast to `string[]`, but, I think `Extract` gives you a better chance of being more specific than that. I've never seen Object.keys called on something where they weren't just expecting an array of strings. Array indices are just numbers.

Comment: I'm having a hard time coming up with a good example, but maybe this will help: bit.ly/3727Gu8 (redirects to typescript playground)

Comment: I've sort of gone full circle in confusing myself. Object.keys returns string[], by definition. But in certain situations you have `(symbol | number | string)[]` instead. I'm not sure exactly what situations yield the symbol/number/string union array.

Comment: @DevinGRhode, As far as I can tell Object.keys does not return string[] by default. An object might have some keys which are numbers, or aymbols etc. However, if Typescript only recognizes "a" and "someKey" as keys, it will type the return as string[]. Meaning TS won't type the return literally but by the group. If it recognizes a few strings and one number as keys, it will type the return as `Array<number|string>`

Comment: As far as I can tell the extract solution is wrong, might lead to bugs, and might be the source of your confusion.

Comment: So, I ultimately landed on your side Ben. I prefer creating typed aliases for Object.keys/entries/etc. Therefore, it's not good to globally hide any (potential!) numerical keys. Ultimately, people should _just not have numerical keys in the first place_ as numerical keys, absolutely, have a fair chance of leading to bugs+confusion. By globally hiding the existence of numerical keys, developers don't have a good chance of noticing the issue. (Any yeah, currently I'd say _any numerical keys_ would indicate some sort of issue that should be addressed).

Comment: I am going back on previous decision regarding `Extract`. This is not the most readable code but I can improve it later/answer any questions people may have: `bit.ly/devinrhode2-typescript-playground-code` –– Note when you hover over `ObjectTyped.keys(subscribersSet).forEach(sessionStorageKey` vs `ObjectTypedKeys(subscribersSet).forEach(sessionStorageKey`. The new `ObjectTypedKeys` has the expected type, `string` as opposed to `string | number`.

Comment: TL;DR: `keyof T` does NOT give you an accurate type for the actual return value of `Object.keys`. I believe, `{ 1: 'crackpot' }` code should not be allowed via eslint rule.

Comment: I've actually never seen anyone write this code, though maybe BenCarp has seen a horrible bug caused by this type of code. Crazy things like that have happened to me, and it can be scarring, but then we need to get others that don't have such scarring to buy into respective precautions.

Comment: Therefore, updating my answer below to use `Extract<keyof T, string>` as opposed to just `keyof T`

Comment: Better ts playground link+code: `bit.ly/devinrhode2-typescript-extract-exploration`

Answer (score 13):

I completely disagree with Typescript's team's decision...
Following their logic, `Object.values` should always return any, as we could add more properties at run-time...

I think the proper way to go is to **create interfaces with optional properties** and set (or not) those properties as you go...

So I simply overwrote locally the `ObjectConstructor` interface, by adding a declaration file (aka: whatever.d.ts) to my project with the following content:

```
declare interface ObjectConstructor extends Omit<ObjectConstructor, 'keys' | 'entries'> {
    /**
     * Returns the names of the enumerable string properties and methods of an object.
     * @param obj Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
     */
    keys<O extends any[]>(obj: O): Array<keyof O>;
    keys<O extends Record<Readonly<string>, any>>(obj: O): Array<keyof O>;
    keys(obj: object): string[];

    /**
     * Returns an array of key/values of the enumerable properties of an object
     * @param obj Object that contains the properties and methods. This can be an object that you created or an existing Document Object Model (DOM) object.
     */
    entries<T extends { [K: Readonly<string>]: any }>(obj: T): Array<[keyof T, T[keyof T]]>
    entries<T extends object>(obj: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T[keyof T]][];
    entries<T>(obj: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][];
    entries(obj: {}): [string, any][];
}

declare var Object: ObjectConstructor;
```

## Note:

Object.keys/Object.entries of primitive types (object) will return never[] and [never, never][] instead of the normal string[] and [string, any][]. If anyone knows a solutions, please, feel free to tell me in the comments and I will edit my answer

```
const a: {} = {};
const b: object = {};
const c: {x:string, y:number} = { x: '', y: 2 };

// before
Object.keys(a) // string[]
Object.keys(b) // string[]
Object.keys(c) // string[]
Object.entries(a) // [string, unknown][]
Object.entries(b) // [string, any][]
Object.entries(c) // [string, string|number][]

// after
Object.keys(a) // never[]
Object.keys(b) // never[]
Object.keys(c) // ('x'|'y')[]
Object.entries(a) // [never, never][]
Object.entries(b) // [never, never][]
Object.entries(c) // ['x'|'y', string|number][]
```

So, **use this with caution**...

Comment: I like the direction you are headed. I'd hope that we don't need to repeat the JSDoc signature description for each signature. I think there is a way to fix the `never` situation, but I'm not sure off hand.

Comment: Yeah, I created this really fast and it supports all of my team's use cases, I can give it another try latter on but no promises there...

Comment: I cleaned up some of the repeating comments. I'm curious if you could explain what the end result of having the multiple signatures is. (Also, is repeating the jsdoc comments is necessary? I haven't used it like this before)

Comment: the `interface ObjectConstructor extends Omit<ObjectConstructor, ` seems incorrect/wrong because `ObjectContructor` recursively references itself

Comment: When you declare ObjectConstructor there will be 2 references to ObjectConstructor, the new one and the old one.

Since Im using ObjectConstructor at the declaration state of the interface, it will references the old interface, not itself.

I mean.... at least I think so :P

Comment: with the `declare var` I was only seeing the type override apply in the one file that this declaration is in :(

Comment: I use VsCode, and sometimes, when I'm facing that exact same problem (the interface/type is only being overridden locally), restarting the TS Server solves the issues... most of the times at least

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225488/discussion-between-alexandre-dias-and-devin-g-rhode).

Comment: I had some issues with the keys/entries typing here

`const d: { [key: string]: number } = { x: 1, y: 2 }` ` Object.keys(d)` returns `string | number` which isn't correct as it will always return a string

Also had some other typing issues in our codebase using `T[keyof T]` in the entries (idk exactly what is going on, something with dynamic imports)

Comment: This will also fix the never issue
```
  keys<O extends unknown[]>(
    obj: O
  ): keyof O extends never
    ? string[]
    : keyof O extends string
      ? Array<keyof O>
      : string[]
  keys<O extends Record<Readonly<string>, unknown>>(
    obj: O
  ): keyof O extends string ? Array<keyof O> : string[]
  keys(obj: object): string[]
```

Comment: ```
 entries<T extends { [K: Readonly<string>]: U }, U>(obj: {
    [K: Readonly<string>]: U
  }): keyof T extends never
    ? [string, U][]
    : keyof T extends string
      ? Array<[keyof T, U]>
      : Array<[string, U]>

  entries<T extends object>(
    obj: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>
  ): [string, T[keyof T]][]
  entries<T>(obj: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): [string, T][]
  entries(obj: object): [string, unknown][]
```

Answer (score 9):

## `1. npm install` [`ts-extras`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ts-extras)  (written by sindresorhus)

2. Use it:

```
import { objectKeys } from 'ts-extras'

objectKeys(yourObject)
```

That's it.

---

Here's another pkg I made before I knew about `ts-extras`:

```bash
npm install object-typed --save
```

```
import { ObjectTyped } from 'object-typed'

ObjectTyped.keys({ a: 'b' })
```

This will return an array of type `['a']`

Comment: Since it's literally 1 file, turns out I don't have a github repo setup for this. If you have issues, please comment here. Here's npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-typed

Comment: I recently discovered this: https://github.com/sindresorhus/ts-extras/blob/main/source/object-keys.ts and am kicking the tires on it. :) I assume that these people have more TS experience/knowledge than me, and this may generally be a better library method/function to use.

Comment: One downside to ts-extras is that it won't work seamlessly in cjs node scripts.

Answer (score 7):

See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20503.

```
declare const BetterObject: {
  keys<T extends {}>(object: T): (keyof T)[]
}

const icons: IconName[] = BetterObject.keys(IconMap)
```

Will retain type of keys instead of `string[]`

Comment: Missing actual javascript definition of `window.BetterObject = {keys: Object.keys}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) utility type to conform your param to only the `keys` of `obj` which are strings (thus, ignoring any numbers/symbols when you are coding).

```
const obj = {
  a: 'hello',
  b: 'world',
  1: 123 // 100% valid
} // if this was the literal code, you should add ` as const` assertion here

// util
type StringKeys<objType extends {}> = Array<Extract<keyof objType, string>>

// typedObjKeys will be ['a', 'b', '1'] at runtime
// ...but it's type will be Array<'a' | 'b'>
const typedObjKeys = Object.keys(obj) as StringKeys<typeof obj>

typedObjKeys.forEach((key) => {
  // key's type: 'a' | 'b'
  // runtime: 'a', 'b', AND '1'
  const value = obj[key]
  // value will be typed as just `string` when it's really `string | number`
})
```

All that said, most developers would probably consider having numbers as keys a poor design decision/bug to be fixed.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAZiEAuGA5PAIYBOBAvgFBUDySApsFAHQDWDAnhABQKIBKFtlIBRYsAAWPHh075RADyikJUADxyQmGFE4AHBtrhIANDGikAlmADmAPgGp7GKjBihIsK1AYBbVBNEAG05AF0qCgEgA

Comment: I can't quite make sense of this. I guess, object keys don't have to be strings, they could be symbols or numbers. I think for 99% of cases where object keys ARE strings, is there any point to using Extract?

Comment: This is the Extract signature: `type Extract<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never` and description: `Extract from T those types that are assignable to U`

Comment: Oh, I see. The Extract guarantee's that keyof the obj is a string. So filters our theoretical symbols and numbers that TS can't guarantee don't somehow don't appear at runtime, perhaps due to mutation.

Comment: I see the utility of `Extract` now. Here's a different example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKANgpgLgBA9gIwFYwLwwN6hjAhgLhgHIBJPAWxgEEiAabGBQ0imAIToYHouZzcAngggwoAgA4QAzgGMATgEtxsACZxpRWAGsAdnADuMfQAtcsKMYVSYV2owCusfSN0GbUItaT2psX4p0AcxgtCAFrAApcHRUbADNRYwg5EVwUvB0BGD0dAFp-BSCQsKk7Zxg1HU0YGTTUhDhHRIhyAEoGADougCkAZQB5ADkO8TSpCAiGHD6hjoKghTiBSZAcNcwiex1XfR0aZjJcSi2dvbpiE71djgPWS4MdDgBfKZh21bfQF-BoGDi4OBoGD9ZAQGRQDqhcIRRBIVp4axUORyQQAHgAogAPKAo8GoqFwBJiSSE+DIOzzQIAPipoCAA

Comment: Basically `let foo = Object.keys(obj) as Array<Extract<keyof typeof obj, string>>`

Comment: Corban, thanks for your contribution. This answer is wrong. Imagine the following `const obj={a: "hello", 1: 100}`. This is a valid JS object. But key will be typed as "a" only. This can lead to bugs. I think it is leading to confusion so might worth deleting. Otherwise add a warning that shouldn't be used.

Comment: Actually we are all kind of missing something, `Object.keys({1: 100}) === ['1']`. Object.keys actually coerces numerical keys to strings anyway. But, there's no way to convert `const foo = 1 as const` to have type `'1'` (literal string "1")

Comment: @BenCarp I guess I totally disagree that this answer is wrong and shouldn't be used. I actually prefer to use `Extract` even though it will hide any numerical/symbolic keys, I'm comfortable stuffing that cognitive burden further into the background

Comment: @DevinGRhode, it won't hide other keys. Hiding is great. It will actually give you the wrong type. It can lead to bugs.

Comment: Further more, I don't understand how getting only strings as keys, even if there are other keys relates to the question.

Comment: So, I ultimately landed on your side Ben. I prefer creating typed aliases for Object.keys/entries/etc. Therefore, it's not good to globally hide any (potential!) numerical keys. Ultimately, people should _just not have numerical keys in the first place_ as numerical keys, absolutely, have a fair chance of leading to bugs+confusion. By globally hiding the existence of numerical keys, developers don't have a good chance of noticing the issue. (Any yeah, currently I'd say _any numerical keys_ would indicate some sort of issue that should be addressed).

Comment: All that said, developers could still use `Extract` to handle some specific, individual, funky type situation, but it'd be best to not use `Extract` in a very global manner.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a more accurate utility function:

```
const keys = Object.keys as <T>(obj: T) =>
    (keyof T extends infer U ? U extends string ? U : U extends number ? `${U}` : never : never)[];
```

Explanation: `keyof T` extends `string | number | symbol`, however `Object.keys` omits the `symbol` keys and returns `number` keys as strings. We can convert number keys to string with a template literal `` `${U}` ``.

Using this `keys` utility:

```
const o = {
    x: 5,
    4: 6,
    [Symbol('y')]: 7,
};
for(const key of keys(o)) {
    // key has type 'x' | '4'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern I use for copying objects in a typesafe way.  It uses string narrowing so the compiler can infer the keys are actually types.  This was demonstrated with a class, but would work with/between interfaces or anonymous types of the same shape.

It is a bit verbose, but arguably more straightforward than the accepted answer.  If you have to do the copying operation in multiple places, it does save typing.

Note this *will* throw an error if the types don't match, which you'd want, but *doesn't* throw an error if there are missing fields in `thingNum`.  So this is  maybe a disadvantage over Object.keys.

```js
    class thing {
    a: number = 1;
    b: number = 2;
    }
    type thingNum = 'a' | 'b';
    const thingNums: thingNum[] = ['a', 'b'];
    
    const thing1: thing = new thing();
    const thing2: thing = new thing(); 
...
    
    thingNums.forEach((param) => {
        thing2[param] = thing1[param];
    });
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydaiKWCMQTCIacEYAb0UDHy-XYiGk31AAF5QABGADcimkzM4rPZ2O5ACYBQBfRSodoCWkAOVZXNAAHIGOrQAAfDXSdUChCcQQ0GnMFWIAqKi2sgDaAF01XbNer+OqDQ6BeTGqabTzmea1ZxIBIbQAKACURt9ZrizAlgfjwdDEejwXNPIC4m5AFZvebLYIAsl4GQAKIMDTh8MERwMRCRrkAPlADJKJXNErtdbIDad3MzPfriC9iml6ZUOGaHjIXkQZecwPYcZQjFp7AYzEg-Ap6kSDGBehEXgAROXVg2FvpT0lsafwA5UOrhErQ6egioAPJfMjvQQ7lokBHKgjgKK40h4KATgLjowxYPoKAIIg0LCJcXySGW0QiAYHDYgsTCsBwPBBCUQA)

Answer (score -1):

As a possible solution, you can iterate using `for..in` over your object:

```
for (const key in myObject) {
  console.log(myObject[key].abc); // works, but `key` is still just `string`
}
```

While this, as you said, would not work:

```
for (const key of Object.keys(myObject)) {
  console.log(myObject[key].abc); // doesn't!
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKygXigbwFBW1AZge3wC4oA7AVwFs4IAnAGixzgENaSLq6MBfDDAMb5SAZ2BR8iEvCSpMOPIRIBGRgtbsoATkZ8MBWlAAUQ0eIDWUAJakJiAJTom2UyPwAbCADp3+AOZGkggA2uYAuva8QA

Comment: With for..in, in the given playground link, k is just a string, there must have been some TS error that is making this now fail. It currently fails with a red underline on `obj[k]`: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Obj'.  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Obj'.(7053)`

Comment: With TS 4.1.2, for..in loop seems _no_ different than the current Object.keys, with both of them, you just end up with `key: string`