# Typescript - Why can't I use a key from a callback to refer to an object

Tags: typescript

Why do I get an error `Element implicitly have any type because the expression of type string can't be used to index type Chapter` with the following code? I don't fully understand what it's saying.

What I want is to update the specific value using the `key` from the callback:

```
let chaptersWithStrings = props.chapters;
        chaptersWithStrings.forEach((chapter)  => {

            Object.entries(chapter).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                if (typeof value === 'object') {
                    chapter[key] = JSON.stringify(value)
                }
            })

});
```

And the chapter interface

```
export interface Chapter {
    id: string,
    code: string,
    number: number,
    policies: Policy | string,
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Provide you Chapter interface.

Comment: Updated in the above.

Comment: Inside of `Object.entries(chapter).forEach` you want to go through `id`,`code`,`number` and `policies` of `Chapter`, right?

Comment: Yes, thats right - well I just want to convert any object to a string

Comment: Can you provide expecting string representation of Chapter object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Object.entries(chapter)
```

`return string[]`

So what your key in `foreach` is just string. So typescript will throw this error

So you have 2 options here. Either Add index type signature to your interface or Retype your key:

1. Add index type signature to your interface:

   ```
   export interface Chapter {
       [key: string]: any;
       id: string;
       code: string;
       number: number;
       policies: Policy | string;
   }
   ```

Read more about [index signature](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/index-signatures.html)

2. Retype your key:

   ```
   Object.entries(chapter).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      const objectKey = key as keyof typeof chapter;            
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
          chapter[objectKey] = JSON.stringify(value)
      }
   })
   ```

Why `object.keys` would return string[] instead of `inferer keyof object type`? Well [here is the answer](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208)

edit based on the comment:

```
export interface IChapter {
  id: string;
  code: string;
  number: number;
}

const chapter: IChapter = {
  id: '',
  code: '',
  number: 1,
};

Object.entries(chapter).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  const objectKey = key as keyof typeof chapter;
  if (typeof value === 'object') {
    switch (objectKey) {
      case 'id':
      case 'code':
        chapter[objectKey] = JSON.stringify(value);
        break;
      case 'number':
        chapter[objectKey] = 0; // ! ! here has to be number not JSON.stringify(value) since this is string and you can not assign string to type number
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks so much for that clear answer. Option 1 works, however Option 2 looks nicer - but when I use it I get `Type string is not assignable to type never`

Comment: i add a little example how to fix it. you have to check the type. it is not javascript. alwasy has to be correct type

Answer (score 0):

Snippet below should help you.

```
Object.keys(chapter).forEach((key: string) => {
  if (chapter[key] !== null && typeof chapter[key]=== 'object') {
    chapter[key] = ...; // update the specific value using the key
  }
});
```