# Enforce index key to be of type string (Type has no index signature)

Tags: typescript, generics

Following code:

```
type Schema<T> = {
  [key in Extract<keyof T, string>]?: any;
};

function logoutValues<T>(schema: Schema<T>) {
  Object.keys(schema).forEach(key => {
    const value = schema[key];
    console.log(value);
  });
}
```

is generating a type error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Schema<T>'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Schema<T>'.
```

because I'm trying to access a value in `schema` by the index `key` which is of type `string`.

I have found similar issues but no real answer to my issue. Isn't `Extract<keyof T, string>` telling the compiler that I will only have keys of type `string` and not `number`/`symbol`?

Comment: The problem is rather `Object.keys`, which returns an untyped `string[]`. Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string) help you ?

Comment: You should use `(Object.keys(schema) as Array<keyof typeof schema>)` if you want TypeScript to assume that `Object.keys(schema)` only returns known keys (which is not always a safe assumption but usually fine in practice).