# Element implicitly has type any in transform

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out how to type this function properly:

```
function makeTransform<TObj extends Record<string,any>, K extends keyof TObj>(transformer: Record<K, (x:TObj[K])=>any>): (o:TObj)=>any {
    return (obj: TObj) => {
        const out: any = {...obj}
        for (const k of Object.keys(transformer)) {
            out[k] = transformer[k](obj[k])
        }
        return out;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
const trans = makeTransform({a:x => x*2});
const arr = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}];
console.log(arr.map(trans)) // [ { a: 2, b: 2 }, { a: 6, b: 4 } ]
```

Error:

[image]

I understand that it's picking up the `string` from `Record<string,any>` but I'm not sure what else I can put there? It *should* only have string keys, but the `transformer` should have the a subset of the keys from `TObj`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Comment: Does above link help out? E.g. if you write `out[k] = transformer[k as K](obj[k])`, it will compile.

Comment: @ford04 Yeah, that suppresses the error. Just not sure if that's the right thing to do. Sure seem to need a lot of `as`es in my code. Edit: Actually, there's still more work to do to fix the output.

Comment: A type assertion for cases like `Object.keys` is perfectly fine. That example would then also give you a proper output, so I am not sure, what you mean by more work to do. Imo there is still an issue with how you define the generic type parameters in `makeTransform`, see my answer down under.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`transformer` expects a key `k` of type `K` (your generic type parameter), but `Object.keys` has the signature `keys(o: object): string[]`, only returns unnarrowed strings and therefore leads to a compile error.

You can find possible workarounds in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string), a type assertion is perfectly fine here.

The other noticeable issue is that type parameter `TObj` cannot be properly inferred for `transformer` parameter in the outer function (e.g. you would get problems when [trying to declare `x` as number](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFgMID2IAzmFAK64FTIDeAUMk8mAJ4AOEAJgNISvEAPABUAfAAoCALmTCAlDICCUKHFaCA1vwIxZo+gF969DNlwA6Np179iyALxosOMOa0DkcO3BCtjMchBcYCJkAFs4LWFVEhhqMJFTZAgAD0gQLjsAJRxqLkFSKFAAcwAaT19Rcp5ktIgMu3cdWVMJRmYyH2I4qDDoGRyEPMEecvEUmWFTAG0eAF05B1EK1lEFZElJ00X7ZZ9WOnamKAgwcigQDYIsLawd5YZmJ+QhkjBkAnIwGX2HOnMAddMEZnswehtXqRkBoPrpTC43LZxJ1YvFoHJFo9Qc9PmBpho5n8Ud00VB8Z47PNJFh8Qsjs8QdiTmcLh8vgBuelGIz0SHvYl-CJRGIk3riWhwKTjGQgchhdDopbIFIAKgATAY5Jy+Z4VH9phKpABGUroKQa0qGgDMpqkABYDHNtURiAQADYQcxugjFcRwFTmCLsZEijHIAD04eQ0zonhkavKZuQauQBnKtDjyAAbImZHbU8g5kA)). This type can only be later resolved, when you call the inner function with the actual `obj: TObj` in a currying manner. That is  probably also the reason, why are using so many `any` types - and omitting `any` is always a good idea in order to enforce stronger typings.

Instead the basic idea could be that we base `makeTransform` function typings completely on the `transformer` callback. `TObj` is now a type parameter of the inner function and has to meet the type constraints of the outer `transformer`. In addition we get rid of all `any` types and unnecessary type assertions.

```
function makeTransform<
  T extends Record<string, (arg: any) => any>
>(transformer: T) {
  return <TObj extends { [P in keyof T]: Parameters<T[P]>[0] }>(obj: TObj) => {
    const objClone: Omit<TObj, keyof T> = { ...obj };
    // we have to cast here, only endresult will fit the type
    const mapped = {} as { [P in keyof T]: ReturnType<T[P]> };

    for (const k of Object.keys(transformer)) {
      // just one way of working around Object.keys types
      const kC = k as keyof T;
      mapped[kC] = transformer[kC](obj[kC]);
    }
    return { ...objClone, ...mapped };
  };
}
```

Test it:

```
const trans = makeTransform({
  a: (x: number) => String(x * 2),
  b: (x: string) => parseInt(x)
});

const res0 = [{ a: 1, b: "11" }, { a: 2, b: "22" }].map(trans);
const res1 = [{ a: 1, b: "11", c: new Date() }, { a: 2, b: "22", c: {} }].map(trans);
const res2 = [{ a: 1 }, { a: 2, b: "22" }].map(trans); // error: b not found (OK)
const res3 = [{ a: 1, b: "11" }, { b: "22" }].map(trans); // error: a not found (OK)
const res4 = [{ a: "1", b: "11" }, { a: 2, b: "22" }].map(trans); // error: 'a' incompatible (OK)
const res5 = [{ a: 1, b: "11" }, { a: 2, b: 22 }].map(trans); // error: 'b' incompatible (OK)

console.log(res0); // [{ a: "2", b: 11 }, { a:"4", b: 22 }]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#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-oQADMFF7oe9EPqB1GhAxT5MfhIKEWxSwcfQuDcYoqB8QJvxKmwIniZmJGOL+AAssmKWBCkgReymUXRqnPmUzEEax7GClxpCKAA5KgwVorwyBTrA3hdLsUhiRJ1kvAArA5QHOWernITRaHOU+3kaVp-mcfpQWIMF3jhSIkXRTAsXxYl64GnAcWzD0ohSJuJXhIBj5Oce55ueWJ62QNt7ka+lBAA)

Comment: This produces a better output but assumes all the transformation functions are the same :-( Errors with `const trans = makeTransform({ a: (x: number) => 'aaa' , b: (x:string)=>true});` for example.

Comment: Oh, I somehow assumed, that you want to convert only one picked property in the object. Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I should have used a better example. Your new solution looks great! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to user [k48](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6269864/k48) (answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55721107/5536304)

The following solution compiles:

```js
function makeTransform<TObj extends Record<string, any>, K extends keyof TObj>(transformer: Record<K, (x: TObj[K]) => any>): (o: TObj) => any {
    return (obj: TObj) => {
      const out: any = { ...obj }
        for (const k in transformer) {
          out[k] = transformer[k](obj[k]);
        }
        return out;
    }
}

const trans = makeTransform({ a: x => x * 2 });

const arr = [{a:1,b:2},{a:3,b:4}];
console.log(arr.map(trans)) // [ { a: 2, b: 2 }, { a: 6, b: 4 } ]
```