# How to create a union type of indexes of a constant array with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a constant array of strings e.g.

```
const emojis = ['', '', '', '', ''] as const
```

And I want to have a type that contains a union of the indexes of that array e.g.

```
type emojiIndexes = IndexesOfArray<typeof emojis> // => 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

So that I don't allow using `number` and use only the exact number of the indexes in the array

And if the array size e.g.

```
// changed from this
// const emojis = ['', '', '', '', ''] as const
// to this 
const emojis = ['', '', ''] as const // removed 2 emojis
```

Than, `IndexesOfArray<typeof emojis>` would be `0 | 1 | 2`

How can I create `IndexesOfArray` that would create a union type with the indexes of the constant array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution: ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAkgOwCYEsDGEDOAPAIJQQAewEm+UAhmiANoC6AfAFBTdQC8UpClRpQmDEABooAOllY0AMwgAnWCy48A-LATJ02PERhsoAH1hMA5MjQBzYAAtL6nlABcUNBABuKjh1BIKAAxAHtQvlFLBXDLKUsAIzplOKhEugAvVMsARzhybLys9Q4AelKoAAYzKAAWGoBmGoAmGoBGAPBoMND9XAJI+CRUTH6iHs4gA))

```js
type TupleIndices<A extends any[]>
    = A extends [any, ...infer T]
    ? TupleIndices<T> | T['length']
    : never
```

Example:

```js
type Foo = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quz']

// 0 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1
type FooIndices = TupleIndices<Foo>
```

Because the solution is recursive, it will fail for moderately long tuples. If you need this to work for longer tuples, you can try a tail-recursive version: ([Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgrmANhAkgOwCYEsDGEDOAPAIJQQAewEm+UAhmiANoC6ANFMTjlALxRoIANwgAnAHwAoKDL6cylahlpMGIDgDotWNADMxsFtNkB+WAmTpseIjA5ceAH1hMA5MjQBzYAAtXLKVkoAC5ObklJUEgoADEAezi5JmMZAAYOAEYOACYOAGYOABYOAFYOADYOAHYOAA4OAE42FKh0qCyoXKgCqGKoMqhKqBqoeqgmlraOrp6+gaGRsYmgqZz8otKK6rrG5pXMte6N-q3hnfG92VXO9d7Nwe3R3cmDm6O7k4ezp4uX9sPZvcFudlldXjNjvNHktLmlwbc5qdFs8jJFwNB4nErLgCHJ4EhUJgcURMVIgA))

```
type TupleIndices<A extends any[], Acc = never>
    = A extends [any, ...infer T]
    ? TupleIndices<T, Acc | T['length']>
    : Acc
```

Usage is the same.

Comment: This fails on more than 23 elements though due to the recursion limit.

Comment: @Oblosys Yes, that's likely, but I doubt there is anything better - at least until Typescript introduces support for number range types (see [this suggestion on the issue tracker](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15480)). In general, you can't use Typescript's type system to do "too much" computation at compile-time.

Comment: True, I usually just use the union of strings, haven't had any issues with it so far.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by excluding all empty-array keys from the parameter type, so you end up with a union of just the indices:

```
type IndexesOfArray<A> = Exclude<keyof A, keyof []>

const emojis = ['', '', '', '', ''] as const

type emojiIndexes = IndexesOfArray<typeof emojis> // => '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4'
```

The indices are strings instead of numbers but that should not cause any issues. If you do want numbers, you could use a recursive conditional type to generate them, but this will cause issues with TypeScript's recursion depth. Alternatively, you can use a slightly hacky hard-coded array and index that to get the numbers:

```
type ToNum = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] // add as many as necessary

type emojiNumIndexes = ToNum[IndexesOfArray<typeof emojis>] // => 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgdgEwgDwgZwPIDMCCAnPAQxAB4cA+KAXigFFkBjAGwFckSBrCEAeyyhwAaKF178A2gF1yAWABQ8hjzhpgUCAFseAKwCWaalHEByQLwbgED3jws4Cg9q1DOAEPftnAqHsvTgYj3jkqIQNKKsDy8qCQ6lp68EioBjTRKOjY+ESkYRB8ETr6lAD0udSUxgAMxlAAPg4AjGWVxgBMtQ4AzE3GACzGIXLpUAAqPAByLBqG4sWCVYL1gs2C7YIArIIAbIIA7L75fggIfgYahHAg+1BwEAzoaIR4IN29mtnDGgmxhgPP4q9JuATEJOlMo89GhyFsClRKMUKlAqjD6jDmjD2vIgA)

Comment: Perfect! But is it possible to make it into numbers? the `keyof A` are string

Comment: Ah yes, was just typing a line about that. I don't think you can easily get numbers. Let me have a look.

Answer (score 0):

We can leverage the fact that `keyof` an array yields a union of all methods available on an array, like `push`, `concat`, `map` etc and if the array is of fixed length (i.e. a tuple) it also adds the indices into this union. So, we can extract just the indices from the union using `Exclude`.

```
type Indices<TArr> = Exclude<keyof TArr, keyof []>;
```

But we might also want to add a proper constraint to `TArr` that would ensure that we only pass fixed length arrays to `Indices`.

```
type Indices<TArr extends readonly [] | [any, ...any]> = Exclude<keyof TArr, keyof []>;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a [simpler version here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63904714/1130377) that comes out to this, if you document how the cleverness works:

```
/** Given a const array, return the union of all its numeric indices */
export type ArrayIndices<T extends readonly unknown[]> = Exclude<
    Partial<T>["length"], // the union of all array lengths up to the length of the T array
    T["length"] // …save that last, which isn't indexable, as last indexable element is n-1
>;
```

I e:

```
const emojis = ['', '', '', '', ''] as const;
type indices = ArrayIndices<typeof emojis>;
//   ^? type indices = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```