# TypeScript: How to type when a object property is accessed using [ ]?

Tags: typescript, object, types, interface

The second parameter of the function is supposed to be a list of attribute/value pairs in an object, typed by interface IModification.

```
interface IModification {
    'envState.config.name'?: string;
}

const initialState : IAppState = mockStoreData.default;

export const mountWithProvider = (component : JSX.Element, modifications : IModification = {}) => {
    const state = cloneDeep(initialState);

    Object.keys(modifications).map(modification => set(state, modification, modifications[modification]));
    ...
```

The error message I get is:

> ```
> src/test/__mocks__/storeMock.tsx:21:77 - error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IModification'.
>   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IModification'.
> ```
>
> Object.keys(modifications).map(modification => set(state, modification, modifications[modification]));

I'm puzzled (and new to TypeScript): How do I have to type modifications[modification]?

Comment: Duplicate of [TypeScript: Object.keys return string[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be a [mcve] but I'd suggest `(Object.keys(modifications) as Array<keyof typeof modifications>)` in place of `Object.keys(modifications)`, keeping in mind that you have to assert that because an object of type `IModifications` might have more properties than laid out in your type definitions, because object types in TypeScript are not [exact](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, that solved it.