# Can't pass argument to `forEach`

Tags: typescript, keyof

I would like to ask why the compiler doesn't let me use the callback function to `forEach` although as far as I know `"a" | "b" | "c" | "d"` is a subtype of `string`. Please check out the error message after the code block. I guess I could solve this problem with a `Record` type, correct? Thanks!

```js
const obj = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30, d: 40 }
type O = typeof obj

Object.keys(obj).forEach((value: keyof O) => {
  console.log(value)
})
```

> error TS2345: Argument of type '(value: "a" | "b" | "c" | "d") => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => void'.
>   Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
>   Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b" | "c" | "d"'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get this to work with:

```js
(Object.keys(obj) as (keyof O)[]).forEach((value: keyof O) => {
  console.log(value)
})
```

The problem stems from `Object.keys`, which will return a `string[]` no matter what.

Using this method isn't really safe though; when I tested this, the compiler wasn't able to determine whether or not `obj` actually had keys which conform to `keyof O`

Comment: Oh I see, I had the *assignability* backwards. I have to give my callback a supertype and not a subtype as parameter, meaning at least `string`, because this is what `Object.keys` returns.