# TypeScript: How to create a type-safe mapObject function?

Tags: typescript, function, types, typescript2.0, type-safety

I created a util function, `mapObject`, which is `Array.map` but for objects.

It's used like so...

```
mapObject(
  (value) => value * 100,
  {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
)
// {a: 100, b: 200, c: 300}
```

Here's the implementation. I got a *pretty* type-safe version working, but had to silence 2 errors about using `obj[key]` without an index signature.

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

export const mapObject = <OldObject, NewValue>(
  mappingFn: (value: ValueOf<OldObject>) => NewValue,
  obj: OldObject
): Record<keyof OldObject, NewValue> =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
    // @ts-ignore (Not sure how to work around this)
    const oldValue = obj[key];

    // @ts-ignore (Not sure how to work around this)
    newObj[key] = mappingFn(oldValue);

    return newObj;
  }, {} as Record<keyof OldObject, NewValue>);
```

What's a better way to code this? The function correctly infers what's being passed in, and the return value has great type-safety. I'd love to remove the `@ts-ignore`s, but **without using index signatures** as they hurt type-safety.

Comment: Why shoud index signatures hurt type safety? If you want to treat an object with arbitrarily many properties there is no way around them as far as I know.

Comment: @philmcole Because the user can now access nonexistent keys on the returned object. Trying my best to maintain `obj`'s safety while transforming it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a for loop instead of `reduce` then TypeScript is able to correctly track the type of the `i` iterator variable.

Otherwise, as Psidom pointed out, `Object.keys()` returns `string[]` which loses the property:value mapping.

Here's the minimally changed version of your code:

```
    type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

    export const mapObject = <OldObject extends object, NewValue>(
        mappingFn: (value: ValueOf<OldObject>) => NewValue,
        obj: OldObject
    ): Record<keyof OldObject, NewValue> => {
        let newObj = {} as Record<keyof OldObject, NewValue>;
        for (let i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                const oldValue = obj[i];
                newObj[i] = mappingFn(oldValue);
            }
        }
        return newObj;
    }
```

---

But there are a few different ways of annotating it to achieve the same result, the semantics vary slightly.

Here's an alternative version using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) (it looks similar but it's not an index signature).

This might be slightly more flexible because the input object doesn't *need* to be a `Record` type with values of the same type.

The implementation is the same, it's just the type annotations which are different:

```
    type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

    type MapTo<T, U> = {
        [P in keyof T]: U
    }

    function mapObject<T extends object, U>(mappingFn: (v: ValueOf<T>) => U, obj: T): MapTo<T, U> {
        let newObj = {} as MapTo<T, U>;
        for (let i in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                const oldValue = obj[i];
                newObj[i] = mappingFn(oldValue);
            }
        }
        return newObj;
    }
```

Comment: The first answer is working as I needed, and no need for @ts-ignore anymore! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.keys` return `string[]`. One possible solution is to use type assertion on `Object.keys` as suggested in [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string):

```
(Object.keys(obj) as Array<keyof typeof obj>).reduce((newObj, key) => {
...
})
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=48&pln=7&pc=3#).

Answer (score 0):

Try ramda's [mapObjIndexed](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mapObjIndexed).

```
export function mapObjIndexed<T, TResult, TKey extends string>(
    fn: (value: T, key: TKey, obj?: Record<TKey, T>) => TResult,
    obj: Record<TKey, T>
): Record<TKey, TResult>;
```

[image: example usage of mapObjIndexed]