# Using Object.keys and reducing object keys

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to reduce `Object.keys`, like this:

```
const example = { hello: true }
Object.keys(example).reduce((acq, key) => {
  const value = example[key]
  return acq
}, {})
```

For some reason I am getting a type error under `example[key]`

> (parameter) key: string
>
> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ hello: boolean; }'.
>     No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ hello: boolean; }'.(7053)

I created my own `getKeys` function with a generic that has the typings I'd expect:

```
function getKeys <T>(g: T) {
  return Object.keys(g) as (keyof T)[]
}

const example = { hello: true }
getKeys(example).reduce((acq, key) => {
  const value = example[key]
  return acq
}, {})
```

However I'm looking if this is possible without wrapping `Object.keys`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Answer (score 1):

In this case you could provide a for your `example` variable as shown below to let typescript know that the keys are of type `string`.

```
const example = { hello: true } as { [key: string]: any }
```