# How can I make a complex interface with string indexes with Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

How do I make an interface that’s distinct but allows me to index it’s values:

```
export const convertKeyNames = (Doc: MyDoc) => {
  return Object.keys(Doc).reduce((doc, key) => {

    return {
      [key[0].toLowerCase() + key.slice(1)]: Doc[key],
    };

  }, {});
};
```

I get a typescript error for this saying:

**Expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyDoc'**

I don't want to convert `MyDoc` into a generic interface for an object with string indexes because it's being used further up the chain.

I want to retain the `MyDoc` interface.

Also as a side note, this makes no sense to me. Why can't I use the object's own keys to index it with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to just transform the keys of the input object. Consider creating the new object by mapping the object's entries instead:

```
export const convertKeyNames = (Doc: MyDoc) => (
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(Doc).map(
      ([key, val]) => [key[0].toLowerCase() + key.slice(1), val]
    )
  )
);
```

> Why can't I use the object's own keys to index it with?

For [some strange reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string), `Object.keys` returns `Array<string>`, rather than `Array<keyof param>`. Easiest alternative is to use `Object.entries` instead, to extract the key and value at once.