# Mapping returns undefined when calling it through map but will return value with explicit typing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapping

I have a record with some matching data.

Consider this:

```
{Object.keys(record['matchData']).map((p) => (<p>{p}</p>))}
```

Will return `name`, `id`, `alias`

Expanding on this, calling it like that:

```
{Object.keys(record['matchData']).map((p) => (<p>{record['matchData']['name'}</p>))}
```

Will return 3 rows, each populated with name.

**However, calling it like this**

```
{Object.keys(record['matchData']).map((p) => (<p>{record['matchData'][p]}</p>))}
```

Will crash the page and the result is undefined.

Why does explicitly calling `['name']` works, but `[p]` (which contains `name`) does not?

Comment: This seems like it *should* work, but it's very convoluted. Why not just map the object values instead?

Comment: @DrewReese Pretty new to this, I want to display key: value in a row, so I thought doing it like <p> {p} : {record['matchData'][p]}</p> - if there's a better way, can you suggest it please?

Comment: Use `Object.entries` to get an array of the key-value pairs, then you can map them together. `Object.entries(record.matchData).map(([key, value]) => <p>{key}: {value}</p>)`

Comment: You have problems accessing `p` because `Object.keys()` just returns `string[]` instead of the specific literal keys.  So `p` is just a `string` and you don't know that it's actually a valid key.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)