# Typescript declaration of a Record with a limited set of fields

Tags: typescript

I have the following code:

```js
type MyDict = {
  [k: string]: unknown;
};

function fn<T extends MyDict>(items: T) {
  const functionDict: { [k: string]: (val: keyof T) => void } = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.keys(items).map((key: keyof T) => [
      key,
      (val: keyof T) => console.log(val),
    ]),
  );
}
```

is there a way to declare `functionDict` as an object (or a `Record<>`) whose keys are explicitly `key of T` instead of the generic `string`?

For instance, if I call

```js
type MyExtendedDict = MyDict & {
  foo: number;
  bar: number;
}

fn<MyExtendedDict>({
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
})
```

I want to make explicit that the keys of the dictionary would be "foo" and "bar".

Comment: Your issue might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string) and [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870)

Comment: Was the solution I provided not what you were looking for? If I misunderstood anything or I can help further, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No matter what, it seems that `Object.fromEntries` will always have string as keys.

A possible solution:

```
function fn<T extends Record<string, any>>(items: T) {
  const entries = new Map<keyof T, (val: T[keyof T]) => void>(Object.keys(items).map((key: keyof T) => [
      key,
      (val: T[keyof T]) => console.log(val)
    ]))
    
  const functionDict = Array.from(entries).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => {
    obj[key] = value
    return obj
  }, {} as Record<keyof T, (val: T[keyof T]) => void>);

  return functionDict
}

fn({
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
})
```

What we get from Typescript:

```
function fn(items: {
    foo: number;
    bar: number;
}): Record<"foo" | "bar", (val: number) => void>
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=6#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMMAeAKogpgDylsAEwGdEAlLCOAJ0NWKmpjAHMAaRAQzAE8A+PgAoY+ALbEAXInQBKRAG8AUIkRUwDbGEYwspALyIwWAO6IAspwAOqANZYecYNI6CAbpwA2U9AG07Dp3QAXTk9PkRXOBhCIQB5ACMAK0ooADp-YmExYhlU0StBQX8pf0dpUPCfZRUa-zZqmsQ3T28-ezLgitUEYjgPLFSPOBZmjxkGxBDxxuq1DVBIWAQAERhoRAMAQWpqTh5U4Go4UUECbV1c6ixCEAgsQrgkjjaeDncPECwQjfClRsfEi8ghsIp5PhMrlAQNQkADqgBfDjyeFcUgUKi0WztQIud6tUqBb5hCJRGIyADcimqkOhSAW0HgYFW0EU8KpKEEf2QcDgUgAjPUVPFONQpAAmVkyIA)