# mapping a nullish object gives typescript error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm mapping a nullish object and it give me an error:

```
Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Partial<Point>'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Partial<Point>'.
```

It only happens when I try to access the value of the object with the key like `obj[key]` and not when I explicitly take it with the name on the key like `obj.keyname`.

Code:

```js
interface IPoint {
    x: number;
    y: number;
    z: number;
}

interface IScene {
    aspectratio: Partial<IPoint>;
}

interface IObject {
    scene?: Partial<IScene>;
}


const obj: IObject = {
    scene: {
        aspectratio: {
            x: 1,
            y: 2,
            z: 3
        }
    }
}
const { scene } = obj;
{
    scene?.aspectratio
        && (Object.keys(scene.aspectratio) as (keyof typeof scene.aspectratio)[]).map((key) => 
(console.log(scene.aspectratio[key])))//the problem in the console.log
}
```

If I change the value to something like `scene?.aspectratio?.x` it gives me the value without error.

EDIT: I've added a typescript playground, with a similar problem to my problem.
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUD2ozIN4BQyxyAHgFzIgCuAtgEbQDcRJAnpTQ868QF6c6jKCwC+BAjmjwkaAMpIQKQiWRwAzgAcICMFDhhgmSujhRDcADYAeDNnAA+MRKmxEKVAHl6AKx24VEnVFCAB+EzMLG1QFCCUnAnEJBEwQdVxMX0ovX39kAF58XmRguIhKQNViDW1dfUNjIqrmskoARgAaYpbkDmQAJi6e1QFkAGZuknFVcXEUtICSkORRAuRMnxZKpbLQgDoa-3qjSeIAMjPkAApvP109gGsINnUr0qUDrSODIwBKNXU1yebEwMGQYDY2lBOw+hzqP0wvwA2gBdX57WhwTRXK7A-75BzXebqTCWCB7SyYADmbxCn1qegRSOBaN+v0SBCAA

Comment: I think you have possibly misidentified the issue; it doesn't have to do with nullishness; it's about using the returned values of `Object.keys()` to index into the object.  If so, this is most likely a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string).  If not, then please modify your question to include a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mqv1kW) which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @jcalz ive added a typescript playground to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Please edit the code in the question itself to be the same as in your playground.  (Links to external sites are good supplements to a question but should not be replacements).  If the code in your question is the issue then it's a limitation of with control flow analysis and function scopes (see [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998)) and the workaround is to use a `const` variable to capture the narrowing like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXkQ1W).  If that works, and you edit the question, I'd be happy to write up an answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript is warning you that `scene?.aspectratio` may be `undefined`, which is true, because the result of the expression `scene?.aspectratio` is the value `undefined` if `scene` is either `null` or `undefined` (or, of course, if `aspectratio` is).

You may be expecting that you won't get there because you've used optional chaining earlier in the `Object.keys` call, but optional chaining only short-circuits the expression it's part of, not the expressions around it. All that `Object.keys(scene?.aspectratio)` does is possibly pass `undefined to` Object.keys` (which will throw an error, but TypeScript doesn't know that, so it thinks your other code may run).

We'll want to ensure that TypeScript knows that `scene.aspectratio` isn't `undefined`. I find that I have the most success with narrowing the types of `const` variables, particularly when there are intervening function calls, since TypeScript can't (pragmatically) know about the side-effects of function calls on the properties of objects (like `scene`'s `aspectratio`). So I typically grab them to `const`s when narrowing, like this:

```
const aspectratio = scene?.aspectratio;
// ...
{
    aspectratio && Object.keys(aspectratio).map((key) => (
        <TextField
            key={key}
            label={key}
            id="outlined-size-small"
            value={aspectratio[key] ?? 0}
            size="small"
        />
    ))
}
```

But even then, you have the issue that `key` probably can't be used to index `aspectratio` because it's a string, and presumably `aspectratio` isn't `Record<string, x>`. You could use a type assertion on the result of `Object.keys`:

```
const aspectratio = scene?.aspectratio;
// ...
{
    aspectratio && (Object.keys(aspectratio) as (keyof typeof aspectratio)[]).map((key) => (
        <TextField
            key={key}
            label={key}
            id="outlined-size-small"
            value={aspectratio[key] ?? 0}
            size="small"
        />
    ))
}
```

[Updated playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUD2ozIN4BQyxyAHgFzIgCuAtgEbQDcRJAnpTQ868QF6c6jKCwC+BAjmjwkaAMpIQKQiWRwAzgAcICMFDhhgmSujhRDcADYAeDNnAA+MRKmxEKVAHl6AKx24VEnVFCAB+EzMLG1QFCCUnAnEJBEwQdVxMX0ovX39kAF58XmRguIhKQNViDW1dfUNjIqrmskoARgAaYpbkDmQAJi6e1QFkAGZuknFVcXEUtICSkORRAuRMnxZ59LUtf3qjNdKlUIA6Gv2DIxZK3dq9K8xJ4gAyF+QACm8-XVOAawgbHUHwudUeAEpdp8AWxMDBkGA2No4XdLg1wQBtAC64OeyFOtDgmg+HxhkPyDk+20wlggp0smAA5iC9mCGhiYTjwbjxEA)

Comment: I understand what you are saying, and it looks like the problem but I've tried to implement it like you explained, but it looks like I'm getting the same error

Comment: @MeyerBuaharon - **Nice one** with the playground example! [Here's the fix](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUD2ozIN4BQyxyAHgFzIgCuAtgEbQDcRJAnpTQ868QF6c6jKCwC+BAjmjwkaAMpIQKQiWRwAzgAcICMFDhhgmSujhRDcADYAeDNnAA+MRKmxEKVAHl6AKx24VEnVFCAB+EzMLG1QFCCUnAnEJBEwQdVxMX0ovX39kAF58XmRguIhKQNViDW1dfUNjIqrmskoARgAaYpbkDmQAJi6e1QFkAGZuknFVcXEUtICSkORRAuRMnxZ59LUtf3qjNdKlUIA6Gv2DIxZK3dq9K8xJ4gAyF+QACm8-XVOAawgbHUHwudUeAEpdp8AWxMDBkGA2No4XdLg1wQBtAC64OeyFOtDgmg+HxhkPyDk+20wlggp0smAA5iC9mCGhiYTjwbjxEA), I'll write it up.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you did there, now I understand it better!

Answer (score 0):

From your code examples, it looks like `scene.aspectratio` can also be `undefined`. In that case, the `scene?.aspectratio[key]` could index `undefined`. Use more optional chaining:

```js
scene?.aspectratio?.[key]
```

That's even disregarding that `Object.key(scene.aspectratio)` would fail too.