# Filtering object keys with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is a sandbox showing the issue. https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-moon-n058k?file=/src/index.ts

**Input** :

```js
data.types = {
        starter: true,
        main: false,
        side: false,
        dessert: true,
        drink: false
    }
```

**Desired output** :

```js
recipe.types = ["starter", "dessert"]
```

**Solution** :

```js
type NewRecipeFormValues = {
    types: {
        starter: boolean,
        main: boolean,
        side: boolean,
        dessert: boolean,
        drink: boolean
    }
}

const postNewRecipe = (data: NewRecipeFormValues) => {
  let recipe = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  recipe.types = Object.keys(data.types).filter(
    (key: keyof NewRecipeFormValues["types"]) => data.types[key]
  );
};
```

**Problem** :
Typescript never shutups no matter what type I use.

Any help would be appreciated because I'm losing my mind

Comment: What's the point of `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`? It produces a partial deep clone of `data` but you don't need one.

Comment: @axiac no I do ? https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cori-zrsio?file=/src/index.js
  I don't want to mutate `data`.

Comment: Nevermind indeed I don't. TIL

Comment: You don't mutate `data`. At least not in the code posted in the question. You **do** mutate `data` in [`let recipe = { ...data }; recipe.types.starter = true;`](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-cori-zrsio?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Yeah I noticed that after testing but couldn't edit my comment. Thanks for pointing that out! It fixed a misunderstanding I had.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error happens because the compiler cannot infer the runtime type of the `key` because `Object.keys` can return an arbitrary list of strings that are not necessarily `keyof NewRecipeFormValues["types"]` type.

Therefore, you need to explicitly tell the compiler that `key` is indeed `keyof NewRecipeFormValues["types"]` so that it can calm down.

To do that, use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```
type NewRecipeFormValues = {
  types: {
    starter: boolean;
    main: boolean;
    side: boolean;
    dessert: boolean;
    drink: boolean;
  };
};

const postNewRecipe = (data: NewRecipeFormValues) => {
  let recipe = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
  recipe.types = Object.keys(data.types).filter(
    (key) => data.types[key as keyof NewRecipeFormValues["types"]]
  );
};
```

Check this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAchDuAlCBjAlpAYgewE4FsA1AQwBsBXCAZygF4oBvAKCilEioC5GXWorgxXMAi5uAI2zZSEYgDsA3L1b5iaORKkz5SvvzQATCJumzFyqEapVRwE9vN6DudQGt7Z3VAC+S30yYUbDkBKDBsATgkVAxoegAKA2JBbijkdCw8IjJKKgBKOgA+HlYZYChcGMg6KAApAGUAeRgAOjAhG3iG5paBFzkAczQAMxBE5OI8vK9KjIgW9moaxvEAK1RgFtcIECpxwQXwajyW4bRSEVx4i3jtkALaYqSDxaoAbTuoYho77GHYBDpWI4AgkCjUN4AIlekIAurDeNMmP4gA).

As for why you cannot use `key: keyof NewRecipeFormValues["types"]` syntax, the linked documentation explains it better.

Comment: See also [TypeScript: `Object.keys` return `string[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Didn't know we could use type assertion inside a `[]`.