# Template literal key has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

There are many similar question regarding how to assert that a particular key is of a particular interface or type, like this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string). My question is different because the keys in question are made from two parts rather than simply consuming a key from something like `Object.keys`.

This seems to do with [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) but I don't even know if this is a problem TypeScript can solve. Currently, there are many interfaces I have that are full of property names that are predictable combinations of a name prefix, like `team`, and a number part. The numbers are always in some range like `1-16` or `1-18`. I already added these interfaces without mapped types, so they are very large interfaces and I'm hoping to use mapped types going forward.

I'm converting files gradually from JavaScript to TypeScript. Most of the newly converted TypeScript code that is still improperly typed as the `any` type. It involves iterations of the previous ranges like follows:

```
const name = record[`team${num}`]; // num is from 1-16
```

I know that `record['team${num}']` is not `any` but in fact `string` in type.  If I were to simply write out the dozens of property names using dot notation a la `record.team1;` then there is no error and type checking works fine. Neither the simple assertion, `as string`, nor `as unknown as string`, nor `as (typeof record[keyof typeof record])` is removing the error messages from the problematic code. I know how to [suppress](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhCGBbAcgV0QIwgJygXigEYoAfKAJlKgGYqAWAbgCgnRJYFF8oByYTns1bhoANRwYA9gGcIcJACUIAY0nYAJt3mJpUAGRQA3kyhQAluoBcUAHbos2ZqYgA3CDeDXpwbGZsBzJyh-d3Ucax4AWR4qHgAxGLIeACFBJgBfITZobV0CY1MAbQBpcxsoAAMAEkNtdJrtNEwcdIqAXS8fP0CMoRd4XDdsKVltJVUNa3FhmTlOcbVNfKh%20JEIIgEEeABoVznII1N3VxGoIgGEdvaQ6CIARK4trQl3Xd09eADNJSSuQmzC2Ai0V2mRY31wAAoADYQYDmayNew4biEBjmKAAHigADZ0WYANQEgCURhMUFUNm8UDA2AgnzMAA9EZxuHwBEFKdJJLCAHTQyT%20SFDEZzRQqRaFaqGWn0pn1QxmVpQeC6ADWEBAkk%20HCQ0jaUGJzHSTCAA) type errors with type assertions now, but notice the code would lead to an off by one error and there is now no error when it will in fact be a runtime error.

Is there an idiomatic way to *check* the type using TypeScript? I don't want off-by-one errors, etcetera. Some of my code can be rewritten to consume the existing properties, while other code creates new properties from those existing properties that are indexed with a combination of name and number.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] of code that demonstrates your issue when dropped as-is into a standalone IDE like the TypeScript Playground?

Comment: For all I know the fix might be as simple as dropping an `as const` in there like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mAVPPW), but really it would be nice to see some definitions of `record` and `num`.

Comment: I added code. Did that help clarify how I'm trying to type check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use so known **[Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html)**. As long as the teamnames and count are known. A possible solution could look like this:

```
type TeamNumber = 1 | 2 
type TeamName = 'TeamA' | 'TeamB'
type TeamData = { trainer?: string }

// here is where the magic happens: 
// we compute all keys based on other union types inside a template string
type TeamRecord = {
  [K in `${TeamName}${TeamNumber}`]: TeamData;
};

// you get autocompletion for all properties
const teamRecord: TeamRecord = {
  TeamA1: {},
  TeamA2: {},
  TeamB1: {},
  TeamB2: {}
}
```

Feel free to play around with this [TypescriptPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhCGBbAcgV0QIwgJygXigEYoAfKAJigChRJYEUloCByOJAQRdKjYYCEWNcNHaIAIvGDx8UAN5Rg2eAEsAdjgD8ALigBnJeoDmUAL7C6YgEoQAxgHtsAE1lyqUKAG0A0lHVQAAwASOTFkJlMQsPQsbFMAgF0deiRJaQBuKlNMqgc1A0UGGwdnXWs7RxcCNw8xDkJdOVMAGncUxA5yRpa2sX4G%20R7agS7BrKA).

---

**EDIT:**

You can also create the **TeamNumber** type from an array if you need to itereate through the values of the **TeamNumber**. Thus there is no need for a `const max` variable to prevent falsy values inside the iteration.

```
const teamNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4] as const;

type TeamNumber = typeof teamNumbers[number];
type Team = 'team';
type VerboseTeamRecord = Teams & {
  id: number;
  event: string;
  gender: 'M' | 'F' | 'B';
};
type Teams = {
  [K in `${Team}${TeamNumber}`]: string;
};

let verboseTeamRecord: Teams = { team1: 'A', team2: 'B', team3: 'C', team4: 'D' };

teamNumbers.forEach(teamNumber => {
  const k = `team${teamNumber}` as keyof Teams;
  console.log(verboseTeamRecord[k]);
});
```

Here is the [Typescriptplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCmBDAtgOQK7IEbwE4RgF4YBtARgBoYAmKgZioBYBdGRA0SKAbgCheoATwAO8GABUkaTDlxE4I+CABmcKRmx4IJMDLzM+Q0RKnyA5AhRnDimADU8WEBHiSUAJXihcAE3lvkAgAyGABvXhgYAEsfAC4YXU1cPkj4ADd4MCh46FwosABzFJgCzJ88eLMAWTMYAB8YMwAxWoazACFrXgBfG2MAgmJwyJIAaWiwGAADABJQgO65gI1ZbqnmHKg8wr5e-gAbeFgM3CcXAM9vOJMUQbC1FDJKgEEzKktkakrO96k6SoAwm8HshGJUACK1PYCdR6fAAOmUIFwAFFEMAABYACg+KzwRAAfGEIjBONAYABreRTD5zXFwtZsAgU+CCFQ3QLFMkgQ7w-YgApYk5nVxSS7InwkCnMACUuzlQA) for the edit.

Comment: Your advice to map the types works. There is still the original issue: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAEg9gGwgZygXigRigHygJlygGYiAWAbgCgrRIoAVCAQwFt0oByYF1z6qgEsAdjwBOAM2YBjaADUIYgEZxkEJmwBKEaXDEATKAG8qUKDzaYAXFGTAxIgObUzF1vht2Hw56fO9iT3snF382MiDvXzNBfRthAFdWJUVQiAA3CFFIkL9HLP1FG04AWU4iTgAxcrxOACF+KgBfGjpoAFFBRwALHiz4JFQMEzMAbQBpKBEoAAMAEiMNViaFgZQmmYBdHJ9qJqgAMmMpuKhE5NSoDKzgHecofOFCsWKyiuqKhoooJoF05jEUEyylU6l42l0BhsnR6fWEayGxzc1i4AEFOAAaMLuYoNLFuQJcADCmOxES4ABFSbEbJgsddslwJHA4KTHs9XqTfjRmYCABRIYBTGwIjiYb6CKAAHigAFYJQBqBUASmMfl0wmQiAgADoEHBHHzgSo1EsIXp9KMZm4FoINptlXsqEA

Comment: Another example: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhCGBbAcgV0QIwgJygXigEYoAfKAJlKgGYqAWAbgCgnRJYFF8oByYTns1bhoANRwYA9gGcIcJACUIAY0nYAJt3mJpUAGRQA3kyhQAluoBcUAHbos2ZqYgA3CDeDXpwbGZsBzJyh-d3Ucax4AWR4qHgAxGLIeACFBJgBfITZobV0CY1MAbQBpcxsoAAMAEkNtdJrtNEwcdIqAXS8fP0CMoRd4XDdsKVltJVUNa1zuQyh+JEIIgEEeABo5znII1PX5xGoIgGE1jaQ6CIARE4trQnXXd09eADNJSROQmzDsCOj1zJYr1wAAoADYQYDmKacJoObiEBjmKAAHigAFZEWYANRYgCURhMUFUNm8UAA1tYyRAQJJnhwkHlKnsamZWkFidJJOCAHSgyT+YFDEZyTjjNTqQpktpQeC6XK45jpJhAA

Comment: I understand. I updated my anwser. Does it work for you like this?

Comment: That works. I think that strategy utilized as much type checking as TypeScript can practically do. Using `type Teams = { [K in '${Team}${TeamNumber}']: string; };` for portions of the records has allowed much greater type checking and less type assertions.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your `TeamRange` type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of numeric [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), you can get your desired behavior simply by using a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) after your template literal string:

```
const idx = `team${num}` as const;
/* const idx: "team1" | "team2" | "team3" | "team4" | "team5" | "team6" |
     "team7" | "team8" | "team9" | "team10" | "team11" | "team12" | 
    "team13" | "team14" | "team15" | "team16" */
```

The compiler then interprets your template literal string as having a [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types), which automatically turns numeric literals into string literals and concatenates strings for you.  So everything then works how you want:

```
const name = record[`team${num}` as const]; // string, not any
name.toUpperCase(); // okay
name.blargh; // error
```

---

Note that there was going to be a feature whereby template literal strings like `team${num}` would *automatically* be inferred to have template literal types instead of `string`, so that you wouldn't have needed to write `as const`.  This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#41891](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41891).

But it turned out that this broke existing real-world code bases (notably for Google, see [microsoft/TypeScript#42593](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42593)) and was deemed to be too weird (see discussion in [microsoft/TypeScript#42589](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42589)) and ultimately reverted in [microsoft/TypeScript#42588](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/42588).

So for now, if you want the compiler to look at a template literal *string* as having a template literal *type*, you'll need to tell it so by adding a `const` assertion.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/FDAuE8AcFMAIBVoEMC2AlJA7A5nAvLAIywA+sATKbAMxUAsVArFQGxUDsVAHFQJxWEADAOJlClMbTEMxzMSwDcIAJaZQ0AE4AzJAGM4iVGmi6A9hoAmsAN7BYsdakIAuWAGdQG1diX3HKclcPLxxfB2QUaiDPbzD-OmiQnztw1EZE2JT-FgzQrIj2XOS-CK4iuIjecvynQWqSpxd3GLyGlHF61Pao5qSKpwTezLbCdKHWrsIc8eLYZQtXTABXFAAjTTDoADdoNU7cTAtNVwByAFkTqhOAMUuyE4AhE5SAehfYADov4ABfEExUNA3JA9HAABIoFA2FJHXQAGyQGjgZkwHlgSLMllchnQJnMFjCsIRSNgKLRyxQ2IiGBw0CUKTJoFgAJQ+HReMsAG0AAb+AAk1gpP25sCQblJplRoAAugpYG8ZikWdAPqBTABVSAwDQAYTF0AAFABKOUK0wAayQ4CVgI+q2J2AAFqb3poNOYQPZGXMLAAPWAEXkRAVCkViiVSsIvABUEbR819rgARP5CEmqCmIuR02RM6hqDnYHmUHRC8XGGXsjmUvZa8X2JXSo3ULxm+1BG3CGmM6ns1Qa3XUwWexFCKWR04KxP2ix09GXiAfkA)

Answer (score 0):

While not perfect, there is a way to leverage *some* type checks even over template literal property keys. There are limits to the extent to which the type checker of TypeScript can examine code. As long as the code uses a template literal, there is no way for TypeScript to perform *automatic* type checks but there is an opportunity to use more than simple type assertions by asserting the types of every part of the template literal as the same type as expected. Here is an [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.0-dev.20210825#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhCGBbAcgV0QIwgJygXigEYoAfKAJlKgGYqAWAbgCgnRJYFF8oByYTns1bhoANRwYA9gGcIcJACUIAY0nYAJt3mJpUAGRQA3kyhQAluoBcUAHbos2ZqYgA3CDeDXpwbGZsBzJyh-d3Ucax4AWR4qHgAxGLIeACFBJgBfITZobV0CY1MAbQBpcxsoAAMAEkNtdJrtNEwcdIqAXS8fP0CMoRd4XDdsKVltJVUNa3FhmTlOcbVNfKh%20JEIIgEEeABoVznII1N3VxGoIgGEdvaQ6CIARK4trQl3Xd09eADNJSSuQmzC2Ai0V2mRYqhs3igiHgAA9rI17DhuIwmBCoWBsBBPmZ4RwkNw%20AIhN9cAAKAA2EGA5gRnCaDm4hAY5igAB4CDDYSyzABqXkASiMJig6MkVIAdBTJP4yUMRnNFCpFoVqoZMdjcfVDGZWlB4LoANYQECST74nRtAXMdJMIA):

```
type TeamNumber = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4;

type Team = 'team';

type VerboseTeamRecord = Teams & {
  id: number;
  event: string;
  gender: 'M' | 'F' | 'B';
};

type Teams = {
  [K in `${Team}${TeamNumber}`]: string;
};

var verboseTeamRecord: VerboseTeamRecord = { team1: 'A', team2: 'B', team3: 'C', team4: 'D', id: 1, event: 'foo', gender: 'M', };

const max: TeamNumber = 4;
const prefix: Team = 'team';

for (let i: TeamNumber = 1; i <= max; i++) {
  console.log(verboseTeamRecord[`${prefix}${i}` as keyof Teams]);
}
```

With this pattern of code, some errors are impossible. Though `max` can simply be replaced with 5 to create an error, `max` cannot be replaced with 5 without errors *before* runtime.