# Typescript: add type for key in enum

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

I'm trying to iterate through an enum, but I'm struggling to get the typing right ..

This is my enum:

```
export enum WeekdayKeys {
    Monday = 'm',
    Tuesday = 'tu',
    Wednesday = 'w',
    Thursday = 'th',
    Friday = 'f',
    Saturday = 'sa',
    Sunday = 'su',
}
```

Here I'm iterating through the keys:

```
 Object.keys(WeekdayKeys).forEach((key: any) => console.log(WeekdayKeys[key]));
```

How can I correctly typeset the key value in the loop?

Comment: Why use the keys and not the values, i.e. `Object.values(WeekdayKeys).forEach((value: string) => console.log(value));`? Or is iterating the keys a Typescript specific behavior?

Comment: Oh wow, I've been thinking way too complicated about this .. This solves my problem, thank you! @DrewReese

Comment: Ok, welcome. You can probably just delete this post then if you don't need it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The answer [TypeScript: Object.keys return string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string) isn't exactly pretty for this, but it *has* been touched on before. As stated in the linked issue in the linked post, it's an intentional choice by the TS devs. See more about that issue [on the issue post here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870)