# Typescript error No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm pretty new to TS...I have this particular type:

```
export type MyType = {
  high: {
    age: number;
    preview: [{ [key: string]: string | number }];
  };
  low: {
    age: number;
    preview: [{ [key: string]: string | number }];
  };
  medium: {
    age: number;
    preview: [{ [key: string]: string | number }];
  };
};
```

I map through my Data object keys:

```
{Object.keys(data)          
         .map((item: string, key: number) => {
            return (
              data &&
              data[item]?.preview && (
                < component here >
              )
            );
          })}
```

The data type is correct, but TS complains about "data[item]?.preview".

It says:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'MyType'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'MyType'.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that the keys of `MyType` can only have three values : "medium" , "high" and "low".

But your item is of type `string` and this can include any string. TS complains.

Now you would think that you can add something like

```
objKeys.map((item: keyof MyType, key: number) => {
```

and this should work.
But TS with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is not returning an array of keys but still an array of strings. This [Github thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12870) shows that this is not gonna change in future.

So one way could be to add an intermediate step and typecast it using the `as` keyword:

```
{let objKeys = Object.keys(data) as Array<keyof MyType>          
         objKeys.map((item: keyof MyType, key: number) => {
            return (
              data &&
              data[item]?.preview && (
                < component here >
              )
            );
          })}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCyiAqzUF44DeAsAFBxwAWAlgOYUBchp55AhjcIwHYCuAtgCNgUANzMWYKMABuVYAHdGAbQJwlAa2CJGAZxhQqXGgF1d+wzTgAfOL0HC4AX2NiyT1+QA2ERUzdsObn4hUXFySRk5XxU1TW04PQMjUwTzI2tbYIdnD3dxPmAAEyp+RmJ-OHZOTPtQiojZBWVVDS0zJJN2iwy7EKcXcUdXIdJST2B4QtYYVjhGDGwUOHxyyloGPxZKwLgAJgAaMLgGqOa4AHI+CAguC8Zzz3WYc-7Bw7dvX1WWKsYDo5OTTUqku11u53ujzoz1ebkc7xYBWKpU2Px2-3qUka0RBVxudwuUIoMOcb1GJBGJFIqi2XgmcAgAgAVgBpLQ6ZZwADyzOAAGMYAA6OI6AAUUxmAEpKhyAIJQKCsRAAHjiEAAZugsDgAHxHLaM1nswV8VhgUWiqgwYB8RhqzULHD7OBxIK1aW4HWo2m0qQwHhQW6i-U+lgS2YAMgjIdDcHDSitNuMAH5BYD5HAo3BgxVY1tlXA+RA+JAuMAuPAKMJUHrc3nJTHaZLcrHHJLHEA)

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Now it says:

Argument of type '(item: keyof MyType, key: number) => JSX.Element | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => Element | undefined'.
  Types of parameters 'item' and 'value' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof MyType'.

It doesnt complain anymore about:  data[item]?.preview

Comment: I have added the playground link too. Have you made the intermediate object objKeys. Please check the answer, and maybe add a similar Playground link to show your issue

Comment: Yes, I've created the variable 
 const tabsKeys = Object.keys(data) as Array<keyof MyType>;

In the loop I have:

 {tabsKeys
          .map((item: keyof MyType, key: number) => {
            return (
              data &&
              data[item]?.preview && (
                  <Component
                    data={data && data[item].preview}
                  />
              )
            );
          })}
The <Component/> has as type prop:   data: { [key: string]: string }[];

Comment: Please add playground link. Difficult to figure out like this.

Comment: I've got it..the loop is inside a function that takes tabsKeys as parameter..I did not specified  the type there.
I did 
function myFunc(tabsKeys: string[]) {
instead of
function myFunc(tabsKeys: Array<keyof MyType>) {

now it stops complain, thanks!

Comment: Thanks this worked well for me, I was stuck for a hot second.