# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index' within Object.keys

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I'm a complete beginner to TypeScript. I've had some success converting a basic site to TS but am stuck on this one last error.

```
interface Data {
    data: Options;
}

interface Options {
    name: string;
    email: string;
    message: string;
}

function encode(data: Data) {
    return  Object.keys(data)
            .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
            .join('&');
}
```

data is an object with name: '' , email: '' and message: ''.

The following error occurs under data[key]:

**Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Data'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Data'.**

I've found many results about this particular error but am not able to apply one that will work in this context. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Typescript objects are not indexable like javascripts be default. See https://levelup.gitconnected.com/introduction-to-typescript-interfaces-indexable-types-d66958523518

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with your code. Firstly the properties you want to iterate over are not in `Data`, they are in `Options`. So at the end you have to use `data.data[key]`, not `data[key]`.

The other issue is something that is more common. `Object.keys` returns an array of `String`s. Mapping over it these and using them as any property say `data.data[key]` will cause an error because TS is not sure if `key` is a property of `Options` (not every string is right?) Only some specific strings are properties of `Options`. And for that you will have to use an intermediate variable and typecast it.

```
function encode(data: Data) {
  let objKeys = Object.keys(data) as Array<keyof Options>
  return objKeys.map((key) => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data.data[key]))
            .join('&');
}
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAsAKGSOQBMM4AuZAeQAcxgB7EAZwG4CBfAg0SWRCjoNmLHAWLIQcALYQqLMFFABzDoWIQZcYABsFS1eslyWLOCvnJFykGq498MAK4gEIkMghvGJCAAoyTCp0TABKcQ1dCDBkRgAjACsAaQgATzEAXhokiHcAOgBrdJZA8gi4MQBBKCg4NIAeYrTGGBp6JlYAPglkKBjnKE8ElJL87Vp-f2aIzK6vHz8AVQAlAEkAYUYZWmZvMGn0iIBqZAByTLPkU+8EXwhVze3dkH2yzHyguABtZoBdMJhXqSEHIfKJRigfxnABkZzC6k4QA)

Comment: Look at this similar answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69479640/typescript-error-no-index-signature-with-a-parameter-of-type-string-was-found/69479814#69479814

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense now. Will need to hit the TypeScript books.