# How to preserve type information based on object key in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have items of varying types (`Item`) and these can exist at different levels in my state (`Section.items` and `subSection.items`).

I need to pass these to a different React component based on their type (`Str` or `Num`).

The following code works however it’s not ideal data structuring.

```
type I_Str = {
  type: "str";
  value: string;
};
type I_Num = {
  type: "num";
  value: number;
};
type Item = I_Str | I_Num;

type SubSection = {
  name: string;
  items: Item[];
};

type Section = {
  name: string;
  items: Item[];
  subSection?: SubSection[];
};

type State = {
  section: Section[];
};

const state: State = {
  section: [
    {
      name: "Sec1",
      items: [
        { type: "str", value: "im a string" },
        { type: "num", value: 1 },
      ],
      subSection: [
        {
          name: "Sub1",
          items: [
            { type: "num", value: 999 },
            { type: "str", value: "sub section string" },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

function Str({ item }: { item: I_Str }) {
  return <div>Value: {item.value.toUpperCase()}</div>;
}
function Num({ item }: { item: I_Num }) {
  return <div>Value: {item.value * 10}</div>;
}

function Items({ items }: { items: Item[] }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue", padding: 20 }}>
      {items
        .sort((a, b) => {
          if (a.type > b.type) return 1;
          if (a.type < b.type) return -1;
          return 0;
        })
        .map((item) => {
          if (item.type === "str") return <Str item={item} />;
          if (item.type === "num") return <Num item={item} />;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}

function SubSection({ subSection }: { subSection: SubSection }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{subSection.name}</div>
      <Items items={subSection.items} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Section({ section }: { section: Section }) {
  return (
    <div key={section.name} style={{ border: "1px solid grey", padding: 20 }}>
      <div>{section.name}</div>
      <Items items={section.items} />
      {section.subSection && section.subSection.length > 0
        ? section.subSection.map((sub) => {
            return <SubSection key={sub.name} subSection={sub} />;
          })
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      {state.section.map((section) => {
        return <Section key={section.name} section={section} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

It’s not ideal as `items` is an array but the order isn’t important.

Also you should only be able to have one item of each type eg this shouldn't be allowed:

```
items: [
  { type: "str", value: “String 1” },
  { type: "str", value: “String 2” },
]
```

I can change `Items` to be an object and then im happy with the data structure, but TypeScript errors:

```
type Items = {
  str?: string;
  num?: number;
};

type SubSection = {
  name: string;
  items: Items;
};

type Section = {
  name: string;
  items: Items;
  subSection?: SubSection[];
};

type State = {
  section: Section[];
};

const state: State = {
  section: [
    {
      name: "Sec1",
      items: {
        str: "Im a st",
        num: 1,
      },
      subSection: [
        {
          name: "Sub1",
          items: {
            num: 999,
            str: "sub section string",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

function Str({ value }: { value: string }) {
  return <div>Value: {value.toUpperCase()}</div>;
}
function Num({ value }: { value: number }) {
  return <div>Value: {value * 10}</div>;
}

function Items({ items }: { items: Items }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue", padding: 20 }}>
      {["num", "str"].map((key) => {
        const value = items[key];
        if (!value) return;
        if (key === "num") return <Num value={value} />;
        if (key === "str") return <Str value={value} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function SubSection({ subSection }: { subSection: SubSection }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>{subSection.name}</div>
      <Items items={subSection.items} />
    </div>
  );
}

function Section({ section }: { section: Section }) {
  return (
    <div key={section.name} style={{ border: "1px solid grey", padding: 20 }}>
      <div>{section.name}</div>
      <Items items={section.items} />
      {section.subSection && section.subSection.length > 0
        ? section.subSection.map((sub) => {
            return <SubSection key={sub.name} subSection={sub} />;
          })
        : null}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function Page() {
  return (
    <div>
      {state.section.map((section) => {
        return <Section key={section.name} section={section} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

`const value = items[key]; // Error occurs here`

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Items'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Items'.

What is the best way to model this? Im simplified my example code, in reality I have many more types than just `str` and `num` and their values can also be more complex (eg varying objects not just primitive types).

Comment: Can you explain this : It’s not ideal as items is an array but the order isn’t important. ? Are you okay having a fixed order or do you want order to be arbitary?

Comment: Also, does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69479640/typescript-error-no-index-signature-with-a-parameter-of-type-string-was-found/69479814#69479814 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I did is rename the component name (to `ItemsComp`) because you had used the same names for both type and component. eg:- `type Items` and `function Items()`

My question is do you have a dynamic count of types? I guess not, because you have created separate components for each type. eg:- `function Str()`, `function Num()`

If I am correct can you do something like that?

```
function ItemsComp({ items }: { items: Items }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue", padding: 20 }}>
      {items.str && <Str value={items.str} />}
      {items.num && <Num value={items.num} />}
      {/* other types */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And I am not getting any errors for this one

```
function ItemsComp({ items }: { items: Items }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue", padding: 20 }}>
      {(["num", "str"] as const).map((key) => {
        const value = items[key];
        if (!value) return null;
        if (key === "num") return <Num key={key} value={Number(value)} />;
        if (key === "str") return <Str key={key} value={`${value}`} />;
        return null;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I prefer the first option as you're not potentially changing the value type.

Comment: Is there a way to make TypeScript error if a new property is added to items which isn't accounted for and loads a React component? If I had a switch statement I could use the Never type but I dont think that'll work here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your array `as const`, otherwise it's a `string[]`

```
;["num", "str"].map((key) => {
    key
    // ^?
    // (parameter) key: string
})

;(["num", "str"] as const).map((key) => {
    key
    // ^?
    // (parameter) key: "num" | "str"
})
```

Comment: Im still getting an error: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-fast-4w44bj?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Simplest is to just check if each property is defined:

```js
function Items({ items }: { items: Items }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ border: "1px solid blue", padding: 20 }}>
      {items.str !== undefined && <Str value={items.str} />}
      {items.num !== undefined && <Num value={items.num} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note: Explicitly checking for undefined is important so as not to short circuit on the empty string or zero.

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-resonance-76guuy?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

Rename please, agree here.
You can make it simple. Just check the first value in the array.

```
type ItemValueType = string | number
type ItemType<TValue extends ItemValueType = ItemValueType> = { value: TValue }
type ItemsType<TValueFirst extends ItemValueType = ItemValueType> = TValueFirst extends string
    ? [] | [ItemType<string>] | [ItemType<string>, ItemType<number>]
    : [] | [ItemType<number>] | [ItemType<number>, ItemType<string>]

const test1: ItemsType = [{ value: "123" }, { value: 213 }]
const test2: ItemsType = [{ value: 123 }, { value: "213" }]
const test3: ItemsType = [{ value: "123" }]
const test4: ItemsType = [{ value: 123 }]
const test5: ItemsType = []
const test6: ItemsType = [{ value: 123 }, { value: 213 }]
const test7: ItemsType = [{ value: "123" }, { value: "213" }]
const test8: ItemsType = [{ value: [] }]
const test9: ItemsType = ["123", 213]
```

Tests 1-6 should be ok, 6-9 not

```
type StateType = {
    title: "Hello"
    items: ItemsType
    sections: { items: ItemsType }[]
}

const state: StateType = {
    title: "Hello",
    items: [{ value: "123" }, { value: 213 }],
    sections: [
        {
            items: [{ value: 213 }],
        },
    ],
}
```