# Looping through enum in react typescript render gives error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums

```
  interface ColorThemes {
    DEFAULT: string,
    DARK: string,
  }

  const colorThemes: ColorThemes = {
    DEFAULT: "default",
    DARK: "dark",
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(colorThemes).map(key =>
        <div>{colorThemes[key]}</div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
```

I'm trying to loop through an enum of strings. But visual studio intellisense complains and says:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'xxx'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'xxx'.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Object.keys(colorThemes) gives you a list of strings, but at colorThemes[key] the key must be a ColorThemes-key, not just any string.

But because you know for sure that every key is always a key of colorThemes, you can tell Typescript to assume that:

```
<div>
  {Object.keys(colorThemes).map(key =>
    <div>{colorThemes[key as keyof ColorThemes]}</div>
  )}
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, sir, this is what I was looking for.