# typescript error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

Typescript newb here. I am getting an error on `updatedState[key1]`.

When I hover over `updatedState` I get error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'classTitleObjType'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'classTitleObjType'.`

and when I hover over `key1` I get error  `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'classTitleObjType'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'classTitleObjType'.ts(7053)`

With `updatedState[key1]`  I am trying to assign a value to that key. `key1` is a variable. Also `updatedState` is assigned `classTitleObjType` as its type. So doesn't `updateState` know the only thing type that can access it dynamically is the string 'byID' or 'allID'

```
interface byID {
  [key: string] : {
    id: string,
    classTitle: string
  }
}

interface classTitleObjType {
  byID : byID,
  allID : string[]
}

const classTitleObj: classTitleObjType = {
  byID : {
    "class0": {
      id: "class0",
      classTitle: 'PsychologyRedux'
    },
    "class1": {
      id: "class1",
      classTitle: 'HistoryRedux',
    } 
  },
  allID: ["class0", "class1"]
}

interface ADD_CLASS_ACTION {
  type: 'ADD_CLASS',
  payload: string
}

const classesReducer = (state: classTitleObjType = classTitleObj, action: ADD_CLASS_ACTION) => {
  switch(action.type){
    case 'ADD_CLASS':
      let classTitleToAdd = action.payload

      let updatedState: classTitleObjType = {
        byID : {},
        allID: []
      }

      for(const key1 in state){
        
        if(Array.isArray(state[key1 as keyof classTitleObjType])){
          updatedState[key1] = [...state[key1]]

        } else {

          updatedState[key1] = {...state[key1]}

          for (const key2 in state[key1]){
            updatedState[key1][key2] = {...state[key1][key2]}
          }
        }
      }

      let newNum = Object.keys(state.byID).length
      let newID = "class" + newNum

      updatedState.byID[newID] = {
        id: newID,
        classTitle: classTitleToAdd
      }
  
      updatedState.allID.push(newID)

      return updatedState;

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default classesReducer
```

I thought `as keyof` might be the answer, but no matter what I try (`[key1 as keyof classTitleObjType]`, `[key1 as keyof state]`, `[key1 as keyof updatedState]` the error never resolves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Comment: @jimmy, I don't think that post answers my question. I tried to use ```as keyof``` on ```key1``` similarly to how I did on ```state[key1 as keyof classTitleObjType]``` on the line above, but the error is still there.