# Enum of strings into array of objects

Tags: typescript

I have an enum I need to create an array of select options of but it isn't as simple when the value isn't a number. The following does not work because

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'typeof MaterialSupportType'.

```
enum MaterialSupportType {
  Equipment = 'equipment',
  Food = 'food'
}

const materialSupportTypes = Object.keys(MaterialSupportType).map(key => ({
  value: MaterialSupportType[key], name: key
}));
```

It's probably an easy question but tricky for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use **reduce** function in order to accumulate data to the end.

```
enum MaterialSupportType {
  Equipment = 'equipment',
  Food = 'food'
};

const materialSupportTypes = Object.entries(MaterialSupportType).reduce((k, v) => {
    const [key, value] = v;
  return {...k,  ...{[key]: value}};
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for: use `Object.values()` instead of `Object.keys()`, and transform the value as you see fit:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYOwrgtgBAsghgF2AJwJZwDYGUwAdcD2yCAKgJ67BQDeAsAFBRQCiAjmKrhKAlALxQA5Gw5ceggDQMmAMQIEAJvyFzFghgF8A3AwYBjAiADOvCIhTpseQsXKUjygPIAjAFbA9CAHQA3TGGAjAAp4JDRMHHwiUgpgAEovM1wgk2R+AD4oILpGKBA4bgAuKFSpXL8MAOLUrwQCABkCAHcUAGE4I2AguLKNOLidel16A2MCDGAvDAIAcyCzMMtImxj7AeGAeg2oAG0GLaYafe3DqAAifO4z4rORTm4QBDOyg9OzioDr8+B2e54z46HDQvE5HeivQ4XArAL5nVQKZ6At4fGE3ABm8gRSKgwMBAF0GEA)

```ts
enum MaterialSupportType {
  Equipment = 'Equipment',
  Food = 'Food'
};

const materialSupportTypes = Object.values(MaterialSupportType).map(str => ({
  name: str,
  value: str.toLowerCase(),
}));


console.log(materialSupportTypes);

// [
//   {
//     "name": "Equipment",
//     "value": "equipment"
//   },
//   {
//     "name": "Food",
//     "value": "food"
//   },
// ]
```

> See also: [Why does `Object.keys()` return `string[]` in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52856805/438273)

---

Alternatively (if you're okay with using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions)), you can do this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/KYOwrgtgBAsghgF2AJwJZwDYGUwAdcD2yCAKgJ67BQDeAsAFBRQCiAjmKrhKAlALxQA5MHaduIBIIA0DJgDECBACb8hAM0VLBDAL4BuBgwDGBEAGdeERCnTY8hYuUpnVACgDyAIwBWwIwgA6AGtgMjNXeCQ0TBx8IlIKYABKKDgXVxCyAjUoBETs2GtouzjHRKSAbQBdJICrXAzQ-gA+KFc6RigQOG4ALihMmU6AN0wwYH7Imxj7eKdgCsyqoZ0kpIN6Q3oTcwIMYACMAgBzVyso21iHBOd1rYB6e6gKhkemGlen96gAIm7uH79H5sDhcHg-IZvb4-UYYcaA34iUHiBA-T7vHSQr4fehQ95-HrABE-BTKCHo6Gw+FAjRkilQTHoqoMIA)

```ts
enum MaterialSupportType {
  Equipment = 'equipment',
  Food = 'food'
};

const materialSupportTypes = (Object.keys(MaterialSupportType) as (keyof typeof MaterialSupportType)[]).map(key => ({
  name: key,
  value: MaterialSupportType[key],
}));


console.log(materialSupportTypes);

// [
//   {
//     "name": "Equipment",
//     "value": "equipment"
//   },
//   {
//     "name": "Food",
//     "value": "food"
//   },
// ]
```