# How do you properly infer the key of an index signature?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I've been struggling with generic + mapped + inferred types in TypeScript, quite possibly I'm overcomplicating things but I basically have a function that returns an object with the same keys as the input object, but with each value mapped (via a function). I created a standalone sandbox to show the issue in one file:

https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-s6jwzn?file=/index.ts

Summary of code:

```js
const factories = {
  type1: function createInstance1(instance1Properties: Type1Props): Type1Instance { /* ... */ },
  type2: function createInstance2(instance2Properties: Type2Props): Type2Instance { /* ... */ }
}

// example input for function
const input = {
  type1: { /* valid Type1Props */ },
  // no type2 here
}

// expected output shape
const output = {
  type1: { /* valid Type1Instance */ },
  // no type2 here, matching input
}
```

The function implementation itself is trivial, but I haven't figured out how to implement the function's type signature. I would appreciate any assistance/advice!

Comment: Looking at your sandbox, you want to ensure `Object.keys` is narrowly typed, but [`Object.keys` will always return `string[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52856496).

Comment: Ah thanks, I just changed that. I'm down to two TS errors. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand completely your problem, but I will give it a try.

> A function that returns an object with the same keys as the input object, but with each value mapped (via a function).

So you have a type of the input and another for the output, with the same keys but different prop types:

```
type Input = {
  type1: Type1Prop,
  type2: Type2Prop
}

type Output = {
  type1: Type1Instance,
  type2: Type2Instance
}
```

The function needed would be defined as follows:

```
function someFunction(input: Input): Output {
  // Do the mapping
}
```

If you want to explicitly define its type, you would use an assigned function:

```
type someFunctionType = (input: Input) => Output;

let someFunction: someFunctionType = (input) => {
  // Do the mapping
}
```

If this doesn't help, can you elaborate in this example please?

Comment: Btw I'm not sure if you saw the sandbox itself (the summary is much shorter). I want to remove the @ts-ignores in the code, and at the end I want TS to infer that `myObj` only has the `type1` key, because the input object only had that key. I'm part of the way there, but can't figure out what's missing now, and have tried a lot of things.

Comment: Just to be clear, input (after inference) should look something like:
`type Input = { type1?: Type1Prop, type2?: Type2Prop }` 
i.e. all keys are optional. I want the output type to dynamically match the keys of whatever input was passed in.

Answer (score 0):

I sort of accomplished what I want with an intermediate function that takes a list of types (e.g. `['type1']`) and returns a new function that works mostly the way I want. I updated the playground at https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-s6jwzn?file=/index.ts in case someone finds it helpful, or has a way to do what I originally wanted (no wrapper function). There are also a couple of things that don't quite work right in what I did (referenced in the code comments), so any suggestions to fix those would be greatly appreciated!