# explicitly say a value as a certain key in TS

Tags: typescript

I have the following code where I pass an object, and want to get the first key of it :

```
      const resultKey = Object.keys(data)[0];
      if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(data, resultKey)) {
        return { hasMore: false, options: [] };
      }
```

now if the above pass, then `data` do contains `resultKey` so I would like this to not fail

```
data[resultKey]?.total
```

right now I get prompted with

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'QueryResult<Q, V>'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'QueryResult<Q, V>'

I know it s not ideal, but how can I specify that that type is safe (knowing that `resultKey` can be anything.

Comment: I'm not quite following here. If you get a key from an object, why do you need to check again whether that key exists in the object? And what's the type definition of `QueryResult`? Are you just looking for a way to tell the compiler: "Trust me, I know what I'm doing?"

Comment: basically yes, `QueryResult` is a graphql query result, and usually there is a key to access the data which is the name of the query. I am trying to make something generic, so wathever query I pass, this function will read get the key `resultKey` and then I want the compiler to trust me on the fact that `resultKey` is an available key of that object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)