# Get properties of an object so that it can be used as keys for extracting its value

Tags: typescript

I have a simple function to extract properties out of an object. I want to use them to be able to build  type of the object. However, when I use the Object.keys() method, the compiler complains that the key is not assignable. here is the code:

```
        interface BaseUser {
         name: string,
         age: number,
        }

       interface User {
         name: string,
         age: number,
         dob: number,
         title: string
       }

       const userBase: BaseUser = {
         name: 'Somner',
         age: 12,
      }

       const userInfo: User = {
         name: 'Somner',
         age: 12,
         dob: 122223,
         title: 'Mr'
      }

      function buildBasicUser(n: BaseUser, u: User) {
        const basicUser: BaseUser = {} as BaseUser;
        const uKeys = Object.keys(u);
        console.log(`uKeys are ${uKeys}`); // as expected: name, age, dob, title
        for (const k of Object.keys(basicUser)) {
            if (k in uKeys) { // Does not work
                basicUser[k] = u[k];
            }
        }
        return basicUser;
    }

     const userResult = buildBasicUser(userBase, userInfo);
     console.log(`User result is ${JSON.stringify(userResult)}`);
```

I know I can do, getProperty(espyObj, 'name') but then I will have to do it for all the properties, and I have objects which have a lot of properties. I would expect the key of the object to match a property to use to extract it using Object.keys but it seems incompatible with that used in keyof.  How can I achieve using the keys so i can use the getProperty method? I know I can use the properties one by one, but that would be so manual. As for the cast that is not a problem.

Comment: It is unconventional to use a lowercase name like `espy` for an interface.  UpperPascalCase is the standard convention; please change this to `Espy`.

Comment: I don't understand why you're not writing `const e: Espy = {...n}`.  The particular approach you're using is fraught with problems, of which you've only mentioned one.  (Doesn't `const e: Espy = {}` give you an error?)   Your particular `Object.keys()` question is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52856496/2887218), but there's more going on here.

Comment: The object in question has many fields which in the original object and the one being copied into.  I simply wanted to test if i could actually copy fields from one object using the code, so I could confirm it would be possible. The actual situation is one where I have to copy parts of a larger object into various smaller objects from a third party library

Comment: Your example code has errors unrelated to your question; please fix these.  For this to be a [mre] someone should be able to paste your code in an IDE and demonstrate the issue you're seeing and only the issue you're seeing.  Also, again, your interface names are unconventional; unless you want to have a discussion about naming conventions, I'd strongly recommend changing them to conform: i.e., change them to `Basic` and `User`.

Comment: This is... still not a [mre].  You write `Object.keys(basicUser)` which is going to be `[]` in your example.  And you've ignored `n`.  Did you mean `Object.keys(n)`?  Could you quadruple-check that your example code actually demonstrates your issue and only your issue?  Otherwise we're spending time talking about unrelated things.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're asking.  I do want the keys of both objects so i can compare with the keys of the other object. if the key of the basic user is  in the key of User then I set the property of the basic user.  Unfortunately, the keys don't match so I can't set the property. That's what I am trying to solve

Comment: Your `buildBasicUser` accepts a parameter `n`.  Then it does nothing with `n`.  Instead, where I'd *expect* you to write `Object.keys(n)`, you write `Object.keys(basicUser)`.  This is always `[]` because `basicUser` has been initialized as an empty object.  Is all of this *intentional* on your part?  Or an *mistake* in your example?  Do you understand the question now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246952/discussion-between-breendeen-and-jcalz).

Comment: I'm not a fan of the chat feature; I just want clarification on the question, not an extended discussion.  Unfortunately I'm not convinced we can clear this up anytime soon, so I'll probably just disengage now.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  interface BaseUser {
        name: string,
        age: number,

    }

    interface User {
        name: string,
        age: number,
        dob: number,
        title: string
    }

    const userBase: BaseUser = {
        name: 'Somner',
        age: 12,
    }

    const userInfo: User = {
        name: 'Somner',
        age: 12,
        dob: 122223,
        title: 'Mr'
    }

    function buildBasicUser(n: BaseUser, u: User) {
        const basicUser: BaseUser = {} as BaseUser;
        const uKeys = Object.keys(u);
        console.log(`uKeys are ${uKeys}`); // as expected: name, age, dob, title
        console.log(`n keys are ${Object.keys(n)}`);
        for (const k of Object.keys(n)) {
            if (uKeys.includes(k)) { 
                basicUser[k] = u[k];
            }
        }
        return basicUser;
    }

    const userResult = buildBasicUser(userBase, userInfo);
    console.log(`User result is ${JSON.stringify(userResult)}`);
```

Comment: There is a compiler warning on the line `basicUser[k] = u[k];`, does that matter?  While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.