# declare an object in typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have the following object :

```
{
  "catalogue1": {
    "content": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "sourceId": "bookit-catalogue",
        "recordId": "ATEST003-68545",
        "createdDate": "2022-08-10"
      }
    ],
    "last": true,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalElements": 3,
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 3,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 0
  },
  "catalogue": {
    "content": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "sourceId": "catalogue",
        "recordId": "ATEST003-123892",
        "createdDate": "2022-08-10"
      }
    ],
    "last": true,
    "totalPages": 1,
    "totalElements": 1,
    "first": true,
    "numberOfElements": 1,
    "size": 10,
    "number": 0
  }
}
```

I am fetching the object from an API, and consuming it in a react project using axios.
but I am trying to declare it in typescript, so I can use the benefit of typescript during the development, but I do not know how usually I just export an interface with the names of properties, but in this object, I do not have a property for the first data (catalogue1),
by the way, if it is an array, so it is easy.

Anyone can help how i can declare the interface, and how I fetch the data as well?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQ8ZVW) meet your needs?  If so I will write an answer explaining it; if not, please tell me what I'm missing.

Comment: thank you, @jcalz seems to be working, but I still cannot see the fields in the project, 
I mean how I can get the data from it ?

Comment: I don’t understand your question, sorry.  Please provide a [mre] if you want any more information.

Comment: you can see the demo : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-3hpr99?file=/src/index.tsx

as you can see I cannot iterate or get any data from the object

Comment: That is a separate issue and therefore out of scope of your original question.  The fix for *that* would be to iterate your object as an object and not as an array, like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-8kzhhv) perhaps.  But that is just the next problem you encountered after you resolved the first one.  Can I write up my answer to the original question now? Or do you need to [edit] the original question to ask something else?

Comment: okay, I edited my question , and you can write your answer to the original question

Answer (score 1):

You can use a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) to represent an object type whose keys you don't know but whose values are all of the same type.  It looks like `{[k: string]: ValueType}`.  For your example, you could define an interface with an index signature like this:

```
interface Catalogues {
  [k: string]: {
    content: {
      id: number;
      sourceId: string;
      recordId: string;
      createdDate: string;
    }[];
    last: boolean;
    totalPages: number;
    totalElements: number;
    first: boolean;
    numberOfElements: number;
    size: number;
    number: number;
  }
}
```

You can verify that your example value is assignable to this type:

```
const cats: Catalogues = {  // okay
  "catalogue1": {
    /* ...snip... */
  }
}
```

That is still just a regular JavaScript object, and to iterate over its properties you should use the standard JavaScript methods for doing so.  For example, you could use [a `for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), or [the `Object.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), or [the `Object.entries()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), etc.

Here's an example using `Object.entries()`:

```
function processCatalogues(catalogues: Catalogues) {
  Object.entries(catalogues).forEach(
    ([k, v]) => console.log(k + ": " + v.content.map(c => c.recordId).join("; "))
  );
}
```

That compiles without error.

(Aside: note that iterating over properties this way will only work easily in TypeScript for object types with index signatures; if your type had known keys, then `for...in` or `Object.entries()` or `Object.keys()` would run into the  wouldn't be as easy because objects may have more properties than are explicitly mentioned in their types; see [TypeScript: Object.keys return string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string) for more information.)

And here's what we get when we pass your example value to that function:

```
processCatalogues(cats);
/* 
"catalogue1: ATEST003-68545" 
"catalogue: ATEST003-123892" 
*/
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJzHANgewOYCuEAzsgN4BQyyA2gNYBcyxYUoeAuk5ddQjuAjhuVXtWAATJiAIBbAEbQA3KLHEcBKEgCSU5q3Yqx1KBH5QJupizYg8R4wlMYIEgCIvrBuw+oBfGg5fZCw4FiZ5HBwsCDgQYLAcTCwABTg8Emk5RSgEpOwAURjZITBiLIVlVWQYYChw5Ejo2PjqmUqoAHkYIogS8HLkdpzg4mAALwgKkbbs6Gmq-wo-CgoYAhAEMGABZAAHKBwkYmJ0ZPwiYgAKBAxsC8y0O9xCEgBKclFO+QArMzAAHSlNgkG7PB7EN4AmA4KAFRAACyu1Su9AANMgAG4cD4AXgAfMh+CB1DEAS8rnRkABqZAAIiYdJpWIBxMg4ABsjgexuyAJRIBpnMlgkUJ+OFAVzpSnpbzeojeKhWFGJLCJGEGZ3ur1IuM+1Dpt3OrwAjAz9bxDQJ2WBzTRqtQeMYDZJzQAmNEOy3qTQ6CTmulNOjAMAAWiN2qIdM9zoNQthIoDAEEACoFADKKYADFmAMyhgBsAA4AKwAFhL0a9BqcsUg7hcAbdWbdbtDWaLoZNWbpXpWYg4MctoRY5tYRCHBsSyTSGWI5pNk-p08KxVK86YuaXdNq9VtTHHEG3w2g3V6-TK5q31TpY0mC6zx7mUHNWdEfiHhvBr3NTpr1tKO0vT-Yw6VdJgAE4lzEW8NC0CBdADCMXijaDLXjCxEMZVMM2zPMuzdXMiwgt0q1jelaxcBtICbFs2w7Lsez7apBxvEd92QQ9txXVJ0hIBduPyLBz3XASb13UcDygCcbxPLoejXAYxJgu8IAfJ8Olfd9llWA4jhIU5v0uMEynlAB6AAqZAKC-Y0iBNJgcMzHN82LctK2s2zIymZAnLw-MTUI4jSOsiyzKAA)