# TypeScript: Apply generic function to all properties of object and infer return value

Tags: typescript, generics, types

I try to solve the following problem in TypeScript:

```
type State = {
    alpha: string,
    beta: number
}

const selectors = {
    alpha: (s: State) => s.alpha,
    beta: (s: State) => s.beta
}

function createModifiedSelector<T, S, U>(
  modifyState: (differentState: T) => S,
  selector: (state: S) => U,
) {
  return (differentState: T) => selector(modifyState(differentState));
}

const add2State = (state: any) => {
    return {...state, alpha: "abc", beta: 123}
}

// the following works fine
const modifiedAlpha = createModifiedSelector(add2State, selectors.alpha)
console.log(modifiedAlpha({}));

// but what if I would like to convert the whole selectors object (if they are many)?
function createModifiedSelectorsObj<T, S, R extends typeof selectors>(modifyState: (differentState: T) => S, selectors: R) {
    const result: Record<keyof R, any> = selectors;     // which type to use here instead of any?
    let selectorKey: keyof R;
    for (selectorKey in selectors) {
        result[selectorKey] = createModifiedSelector(modifyState, selectors[selectorKey])       // how to solve TS2345 here?
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Link to TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=54#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8CwAoKurwBswALeALigGdgAnASwDsBzAGmzygCMIEKGBXALbca2AL7ZsAYwD2DalQgEIU4DJqUoqTDjyES5KAApKFOIggBKLQD4qAOn2k2u3N17HTsBEmvI7lPbu8OKSWABm-AyqdHJQUjQQFgCyMgAmdOF0EGkwSipqNAA8ACossOUAqjZG7FCC6Zkg5kgURhnh4RCJDMAtEBQlfnYwLriU+arqbdQWZsNQlS7WOriJwPw0DMYdXT19PgNQQ7aKylM0Rg0dzYftmXsQvf2WlgDcoVjScgrwaWkAJn6Wk8hwo8AYIAWqzw6022zQ9iRsyQ5SchgARPBOFIMeVghQAIwAgDMEiw5OwAHoqVBgMRoOEZAQCDIAO6MJhQNnqADWmiyDAg33kwHqjSyOQAgkRSCCEkkkKkOtlcpNCkY-oD+uUJudCoF0ZYRZRmRB7KymFcJaqZQYjGgxK8Pl8sDSuPwxWzSGLMlAAJLcmT8AhpKAEOi86BqeJyABu3TF9Og3rNZwK6k0Mk4ACsCsY-cmQPhEvUIVCAPzYSLRYCxbYKlI2nJ5fWZgDyudK5VGUAASlAIAAPJAMNKaUCQGThdMXSg1a5NfptXbdJ4HObHBa9vUZjQUPsrOq4WSiqCJSgh4AHlTqNJFKMgaf9tGQuyoXdzt4cKDu710KRiDpcBoxkKB+AmKAGVLRhqCSMNn3LKtXHDHhZ0KABpCAQAoR9nz7F0OCZGhPHVdQsOLRh0MzI8UI4C8rwAbU-TDsIAXXlRImxVFsyMuRdwluCxdT4yhmL4ii2OsH9f1pYh2TpMDTQIBNjhgUkABYAFYoLXZCOHJeieHhc8IEvAhgBdMQgA).

Is there a way in TS to provide correct typings for `createModifiedSelectorsObj` and the return values of the selector functions?

Comment: Your TS link is broken, unfortunately.  Also, the use of `K` as a type parameter is confusing to me; that usually represents a key-like type constrained to `string | number | symbol`.  Are you just using it as an arbitrary type parameter?  If so you should probably replace it with something else

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdYbQm) work for you?  It's kind of too bad that `add2State` is of type `(x: any)=>any` since those `any`s completely destroy any typing that you might have been trying to demonstrate.  Anyway if that approach works I can write up an answer; please edit the code example to include a use case where my approach fails.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for your hints. I updated the post accordingly.

Comment: Did you see my second comment?  Does [the solution at this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQxd7W) work for you or not?

Comment: Yes, I just tried it out, it works! Many thanks! Feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
function createModifiedSelectorsObj<T, S, U extends object>(
    modifyState: (differentState: T) => S, selectors: { [K in keyof U]: (s: S) => U[K] }) {
    const result = {} as { [K in keyof U]: (t: T) => U[K] };
    let selectorKey: keyof U;
    (Object.keys(selectors) as Array<keyof U>).forEach(<K extends keyof U>(selectorKey: K) =>
        result[selectorKey] = createModifiedSelector(modifyState, selectors[selectorKey])
    );
    return result;
}
```

The `T` and `S` type parameters are the same as for a single selector, but now `U` is an object type whose keys are the same as the `selectors` object and whose values are the return types of the methods in the `selectors`object.  So if `selectors` is of type `{a: (s: State)=>string, b: (s: State)=>number}`, then `U` will be just `{a: string, b: number}`.

That means the type of `selectors` is a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over `U`, and when you call `createModifiedSelectorsObj()` the compiler needs to infer `U` from `{[K in keyof U]: (u: S)=>U[K]}`.  Luckily this sort of inference is pretty easy for the compiler.

Inside the implementation, I define `result`'s type as a different mapped type over `U`, where this time the input for each method is of type `T` instead of `S`.  Note that I have changed the implementation to initialize `result` to a new empty object `{}` instead of `selectors`, since I can't imagine why you'd want to clobber the properties of the initial object.  Feel free to change it back if you want, but I hope you know what you're doing.

Anyway, since the initialized value (`{}`) is not really of the type we want `result` to be, I need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to get the compiler to accept the assignment.

Then I've refactored the `for...in` loop to an `Object.keys().forEach()`, because it allows me to use a callback where `selectorKey` is of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type `K extends keyof U`.  Note that [`Object.keys(obj)` returns `string[]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string) and not `(keyof typeof obj)[]`, so I have used a type assertion to tell the compiler that it can assume that the only keys in `selectors` are the ones it knows about, which are of type `keyof U`.

The implementation of the generic callback type checks because the compiler understands that both sides of the assignment are of type `(t: T) => U[K]`.

---

Okay, let's test it out:

```
const modifiedSelectorsObj = createModifiedSelectorsObj(add2State, selectors);
/* const modifiedSelectorsObj: {
    alpha: (t: any) => string;
    beta: (t: any) => number;
} */
```

Looks good.  The type of `modifiedSelectorsObject` is an object type whose methods have the same return type as the corresponding methods of `selectors`, but which have the same input type as `add2State`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?&q=54#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGxoF4oG8CwAoKurwBswALeALigGdgAnASwDsBzAGmzygCMIEKGBXALbca2AL7ZsAYwD2DalQgEIU4DJqUoqTDjyES5KAApKFOIggBKLQD4qAOn2k2u3N17HTsBEmvI7lPbu8OKSWABm-AyqdHJQUjQQFgCyMgAmdOF0EGkwSipqNAA8ACossOUAqjZG7HiC6Zkg5kgURhnh4RCJDMAtEBQlfnYwLhyU+arqbdQWZsNQlS7WOhyJwPw0DMYdXT19PgNQQ7aKylM0Rg0dzYftmXsQvf2WlgDcoVjScgrwaWkAJn6Wk8hwo8AYIAWqzw6022zQUHsyNmSHKTkMACJ4JwpJjysEKABGAEAZigEiwlLCsnkwCg10y2TSAEEiKQQQkkkhUh1mXlzoUjH9Af1yhNBepAhj3tgAPRy+I-emMrI5NkGNq7bpPA5zfCQhbUejMb7yGTKewEGRMK6NNWs9nwIxoMSvD5fCJRGJxLkpe38yaFSgAeU4ACtSuVRosoBAAB5IBhpTQyCMFGp1XCq276+6dHXPMHHBYxiUFKUUREAbQA0lBGFAANYQEAycKLAC6M3mp0qdc7FJWWaVdKgiUo-AI9O0Ynwmhr9cbLbbHcq3eMwEGC37tcHYg9HGU9PLF1rrYoK-bi0PeCMYfDBXsK8oJiDUus8E0LJoNHgICKK81xsSx7HCdQAFF4CkYgjCKesEyTFNm1ba9qjfSUaHPEAKFrYYRzWCBJ2natT0KbDB1QP0eQDHIBQrS4czFM4GMoUj3yw1tO0sEdZVccceHhATiOAD1qSwWkFFVQNMNDCNOUSf0+Toji5PDYV-iBQ5xVUvi5QAKlHKTaNyVSHyrEcMTaLcDShU5jUYJhbzcHhDCMGyITs-woAEYRujEqB9LlMIgA)

Comment: Thanks for your solution! I noticed that the refactoring to Object.keys is not necessary, it also works with the for...in loop. The assumption that I would like to use a new object was correct, thanks.