# obj.keys typescript next.js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

ok so I'm using obj.keys to pass props to a component, the below works.

```
       <ul className="min-h-min flex flex-row justify-around min-w-full min-w-min grow ">
          {Object.keys(attributes).map((attribute: any, index: number) => (
            <Attribute {...attributes[attribute]} key={`${index}`} />
          ))}
        </ul>
```

However I'm using type any, when I use the interface as below:
interface:
exported as it is kept in a different file and imported it is implemented in several places

```
export interface attributesInterface {
  attribute: string;
  abr: string;
  score: scoreInterface[];
  skills?: skillsInterface[];
}
```

implementatoin

```
      {show && attributes && (
        <ul className="min-h-min flex flex-row justify-around min-w-full min-w-min grow ">
          {Object.keys(attributes).map((attribute: attributesInterface, index: number) => (
            <Attribute {...attributes[attribute]} key={`${index}`} />
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
```

I get an error:

> Types of parameters 'attribute' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'attributesInterface'.ts(2345)

Ideally I'd like to find a fix for this. I understand that obj.keys will return a string, but I was reading that `as Array<keyof typeof v>` was a possible fix. However I'm unsure if this will work or how to implement in my scenario, for reference I found this possible solution at [TypeScript: Object.keys return string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Comment: What does "when I use the interface" mean? Please edit your question to include debugging details, and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You may be assigning `attributesInterface` incorrectly here. We already know that `Object.keys(attributes)` returns an array of strings (`string[]`), so when you use `.map()`, you're iterating through strings. So `attribute` here is going to be a `string` but you're telling TypeScript that it's supposed to be an `attributesInterface` which has the shape of an object consisting of keys like `attribute`, `abr`, `score`, etc.