# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type ''

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

struggling with typescript here. it doesn't like me accessing accountProps using account in this map

```
export type AccountTypes = "TB1" | "GBB" | "MS1" | "28D" | "RS1";

type AccountDetails = {
  total: number;
  annualRate: number;
};

export type AccountReceivedProps = Record<AccountTypes, AccountDetails>
```

the issue is that account here is just a string and so can't be used to access the props of AccountReceivedProps

```
      ...Object.keys(accountProps).map((account) => {
        
        console.log('accountProps[account]   ',typeof account)
        console.log('accountProps[account]   ',account)
        return {
          col0: account,
          col1: `£ ${accountProps[account]['total'].toFixed(2)}`,
          col2: `£ ${(accountProps[account]['total'] * (accountProps[account]['annualRate'] / 100)).toFixed(2)}`,
        }
      })
```

i've tried

account: keyof AccountReceivedProps
account: AccountTypes

i would have put money on the latter being the correct answer. Alas

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AccountReceivedProps'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AccountReceivedProps'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Answer (score 0):

The type definition for Object.keys is indeed too general for what you're looking for. If you look in lib.es2015.cor.d.ts, you see:

```
keys(o: {}): string[];
```

string[] isn't good enough.

For something like this, I think the easiest thing to do would be to assert that the keys really are the keys of the object when you collect them:

```
const keys = Object.keys(accountProps) as (keyof AccountReceivedProps)[];
```