# use Object.keys() to iterate through Objects

Tags: typescript

why is this example not working in TypeScript:

```
const nationStates = ['berlin', 'hamburg'] as const
export type NationStateType = typeof nationStates[number]

export const wfsConfig: {
      [nationState in NationStateType]: Partial<Record<ElementTypes, WFSConfigurations[]>>
    } = {
      berlin: { trees: berlinTrees, parcels: berlinParcels },
      hamburg: { trees: hamburgTrees },
    }

    Object.keys(wfsConfig).forEach(states => {
      console.log(wfsConfig.berlin.parcels) // works
      wfsConfig[states] // does not work
    })
```

the errormessage is:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '`{ berlin: Partial<Record<ElementTypes, WFSConfigurations[]>>; hamburg: Partial<Record<ElementTypes, WFSConfigurations[]>>; }`'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '`{ berlin: Partial<Record<ElementTypes, WFSConfigurations[]>>; hamburg: Partial<Record<ElementTypes, WFSConfigurations[]>>; }`'.

which I understand (partially) but I have (or haven't I?) typed the keys of wfsConfig by this:

```
{[nationState in NationStateType]: Partial<Record<ElementTypes, WFSConfigurations[]>>}
```

so TS should know that the key is not just a string, but always of NationStateType...

where is my problem of understanding? Or what's wrong here?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)

Comment: kind of... i just figured i am a little stupid ;) i solved it by typing states manually `const elements = wfsConfig[states as NationStateType]`

Comment: @HannesF note that isn't at all type safe, for the same reason that `Object.keys(foo)` is type `string[]` instead of `(keyof typeof foo)[]`. See the linked duplicate

Answer (score 0):

That's because JS runtime gives no guarantee on if the object own keys are of the type.
If you are sure that the object is really a Record or really has only known props, make a custom function:

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=36&ssc=17&pln=2&pc=1#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)

```
/** Use this when you are sure this object is Record */
function recordEntries<K extends string, V>(t: Record<K, V>) {
  return Object.entries(t) as [K, V][];
}

/** Use this when you are precisely know own keys */
function typedEntries<T extends {}>(t: T) {
  return Object.entries(t) as { [K in keyof T]: [K, T[K]] }[keyof T][]
}

let x = typedEntries({ a: 1, b: 2, c: { d: 4 } } as const)
//  ^?



let a: { a: 1 } = { a: 1 };
let ab: { a: 1, b?: 2 } = a;
ab.b = 2;

let c = typedEntries(a)
//  ^?
console.log(c)
// > [["a", 1], ["b", 2]] 

class D {
  f(){}
  g = 0;
}
let d = new D()
//  ^?

let d1 = typedEntries(d)
//  ^?
console.log(d1)
// > [["g", 0]]
```