# How to properly type assigned properties to a class in a forEach method?

Tags: typescript

Suppose the following code:

```
type TDone =  (res: string) => void;
type TFail =  (res: string) => void;

class Effect {
  _done?: TDone;
  _fail?: TFail;

  constructor({ done: _done, fail: _fail }: { done?: TDone, fail?: TFail }) {
    this._done = _done;
    this._fail = _fail;
  }

  done() {
    return this._done?.('ok!')
  }

  fail() {
    return this._fail?.('fail!')
  }
}

const createEffect = (watchers : { done?: TDone, fail?: TFail }) => {
  const effect = new Effect({});

  Object.keys(watchers).forEach((watcher) => {
    effect[watcher] = watchers[watcher];
  })

  return effect;
}

const effect = createEffect({ done: () => console.log('done!') });

effect.fail();
```

This throws an error here:

```
Object.keys(watchers).forEach((watcher) => {
  effect[watcher] = watchers[watcher];
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})
```

How can I properly type this? I've tried different combinations of `keyof typeof` but to no avail.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgIgewHbQLxSgCgE4QM4BcUew2AlkgOYCUUqAfFAG4JkAmA3AFCiSwBiAQzIAbOhhz4iJclVoNmrTly4BjEYLx4oAUQBmeiKuBQA3lwwB9NsggB+IvFvcre4SIcD33C1FXIZAFdjBGxMUygbFCJrWwAaKDdRGKSxAF8iCKj7R0QUBNTPGCFRKDTacwwMYAALMjwAOliUcWaIFyra+qbU1tSOtJUMbMwK3wxcYEDsJCguxra7BswAcgQAawBCFepfQd9U0bNxqEnp2fme9yXV1O3djEH9-yQSP1xBYAh9Q2NxTAA7p9VDUINhtJlIrYinkIAVro4Sul5IxKn4AiYIAYjCZ0CgAbpscZwuUfBgAPIAIwAVjiGusICA8IDgaDwdQGnpQjpBCDMCzgCCwSjjlUoFjfsAANpAwVsgC64llQvBMtZYPlA12vjOM3FROA3GeGP1kvEqg+Xx+OPCUOiWBFLzwCBEEAaIgQlFW2XuZWoPgldMO-qAA)

Comment: You've got a name mismatch in you members, `done` is unequal to `_done`. And in this example why not `return new Effect(watchers)`?

Comment: I've just renamed the parameter names, I don't think there's an issue with the nomenclature. Regarding your second point, I'm using [`effector`](https://effector.dev/), and decided to simplify my situation for this question.

Comment: `effect["done"]` is the method, not the member, ditto "fail"

Comment: And [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgIgewHbQLxSgCgE4QM4BcUew2AlkgOYCUUqAfFAG4JkAmA3AFCiSwBiAQzIAbOhhz4iJclVoNmrTly4BjEYLx4oAUQBmeiKuBQA3lwwB9NsggB+IvFvcre4SIcD33C1FXIZAFdjBGxMUygbFCJrWwAaKDdRGKSxAF8iCKj7R0QUBNTPGCFRKDTacwwMYAALMjwAOliUcWaIFyra+qbU1tSOtJUMbMwK3wxcYEDsJCguxra7BswAcgQAawBCFepfQd9U0bNxqEnp2fme9yXV1O3djEH9-yQSP1xBYAh9Q2NxTAA7p9VDUINhtJlIrYinkIAVro4Sul5IxKqcIFMZlAUADdAYjMBAcDQeDqNxngETBB8X90KoPl8fgTwlDolgUX4AggRBAGiIEJRVtl7mUySpqb9gA1DmSgA) is what I meant. The constuctor of `Effect` already does what you are trying to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript: Object.keys return string\[\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string)