# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"one" | "two" | "three" | "four" | "five" | "six"'

Tags: typescript, types, react-typescript

I have a type:

```
type OtpCode = {
  one: string;
  two: string;
  three: string;
  four: string;
  five: string;
  six: string;
};
```

and try to loop this object and set value :

```
Object.keys(defaultValues).forEach((x, i) => {
      codeValuesForm.setValue(x, 'sometesttext');
    });
```

x Type is OtpCode, and Typescript tells me that

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '"one" | "two" | "three" | "four" | "five" | "six"'.
```

How can I solve this to loop this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys()` sadly returns `string[]` and not a union of the keys on the object you pass in. There are many other answers on this which may help you find an appropriate solution, e.g.

- [Why doesn't Object.keys return a keyof type in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55012174/why-doesnt-object-keys-return-a-keyof-type-in-typescript)
- [TypeScript: Object.keys return string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string).

Most of the time you can get away with just manually type-casting, e.g.

```
Object.keys(defaultValues).forEach((key) => { key }); // string
(Object.keys(defaultValues) as (keyof OtpCode)[]).forEach((key) => { key }); // keyof OtpCode
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8sYGED2ATaBeKBvAUFKSAdhAFxQDOwATgJaEDmA3HlMAO5JmW0PP7AALKhFIVqdJiwBmSAK5Uu43tJoA3Udwl8KNAB6KekgL7McAYyKUoaKQENZAG2AA1Ww9kRyZOIlQZsLPhEogDkwSEANIGsHGQh7EiR0YLCoSkiSfj4MvJxOVSZWVJqocXqhfjkenFVukkmODgwAEYAVhBmwAB0ANYQIOQAFDb2Tq7ungCUXTJUAKK2ZgKDg30gk1DoAHzYUGtQRpOMUAD0J2KGOIMt7Z29-UMjji5uHuQbtuRQq-1IUrDwZBoSYAbQAutNZgslis1httrt9odjmc9r9-j4gRAcEA)