# return an enum type from a fucntion in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

Is it possible to return an enum type from a function in typescript javascript.
Example:

```
enum Fruit{
  APPLES,
  ORANGES,
}

const findFruit= (arr: string[]) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    const result = Object.keys(Fruit).find((item) =>
      cur.includes(item)
    )
    acc = !result? acc : result
    return acc
  }, '')
}
```

I want to be able to be able to match the returned value to an enum but right now its return as a string from the function.

```
const type = findFruit(['I like APPLES', 'I love ORANGES'])

if(type === Fruit.APPLES) {
  .....
}
```

The above will give me an error in typescript `Fruit' is not comparable to type 'string'`

Comment: Your function is returning the *key*, not the value.  I guess you should use the value, and make sure to filter out the reverse mappings since you don't want them.  Maybe something like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXOMVW) shows?  But this is kind of a weird off-brand use for enums.  Still, if it's what you're looking for I could write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: No this is great. Thank you if you want to write up the explanation I'm happy to vote it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [numeric `enum`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#numeric-enums) is an object containing key-value pairs, where the keys are strings and the values are numbers.  It also has [reverse mappings](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#reverse-mappings) where the keys are numbers (well, numeric strings; objects can't really have `number` keys) and where the values are strings.

If you are trying to find whether or not a string *contains* a string key and then return the corresponding value, you will need to change your code so that the reverse mappings are filtered out (so that `'I enjoy 1'` doesn't cause a match) and that it actually looks up the key in the enum.  Perhaps like this:

```
const findFruit = (arr: string[]) => {
  return arr.reduce<Fruit | undefined>((acc, cur) => {
    const result = (Object.keys(Fruit)
      .filter(x => x !== +x + "") as Array<keyof typeof Fruit>
    ).find((item) => cur.includes(item));
    acc = !result ? acc : Fruit[result]
    return acc
  }, undefined)
}
```

So here we are saying that the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) accumulator is of type `Fruit | undefined` instead of some `string`.  We are also [asserting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that after filtering `Object.keys()` of `Fruit` for numeric strings, that we are left with an array of `keyof typeof Fruit`.  This can't be inferred by the compiler because [TypeScript: Object.keys return string[]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52856496/2887218).

Anyway, now the code works and returns a `Fruit | undefined`:

```
const type = findFruit(['I like APPLES', 'I love ORANGES']);
// const type: Fruit | undefined
console.log(type) // 1
```

The value of `type` is `1`, since that's the value of `Fruit.ORANGES`

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.9.5&ssl=24&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=9#code/KYOwrgtgBAYgTmAlgFygbwLACgpQIIAKBAMgKIDKANNrgPIBKeAcgOIXVYC+22AxgPYgAzqgBmiEABN4SVAF4oACgCGcOAC4oIuBIDmAbQC6ASihyAfOhpQ4wZGDggoquADpbksL2AAeGSigAHygwKWBxEGBJc0UVXl5KKF4HUwsrHFwkwREbYCEwABt5JVoAIwArYF5kVwBrYABPIUV-ZGNrTKhXcSLgOEUADzNLIYBCOQUAaiHJqAAiOdNlIXw1ZQafeob+UShkBoAHYB3YBBRzDqhjbolJWJRgCFTLZLcJXgKwSTzFB6fjADcl2U8TMUFGtnyRSgAH5nKDNK19JDCshDJdbPZHPDeNZOIlQt8IlF2lweFg+NlUPsjmCItIzshFPoAOQASSgBUQ9XwRDI5BZiXZnP4ADdgFAGMw2AKTECsAB6BVZYTUw7ARGMoIhMLEySU4T8ArAVwFfi6RQ04CmJVQACM5MQu0t6rME1OslchBIFFMmAy2E4UGABSEEv9gaAA)