# How do I map from a Typescript Enum to objects I generate based off Enum keys and properties?

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript enum:

```
export enum LanguagesEnglish  {
  'enUS'= 'English',
  'zhHant'= 'Mandarin, Traditional',
};
```

I would like to use it to generate options for a selector component. To do so, I think I should be able to map over the keys of the enum to generate objects in the shape the selector component library requires, defined as:

```
type pickerOption = {
  code: string,
  label: string,
};
```

I try to define that type as

```
type pickerOption = {
  code: keyof LanguagesEnglish,
  label: LanguagesEnglish,
};
```

Now, I'd like to generate objects of this type and put them in an array.

```
function generateOption(key: keyof LanguagesEnglish): pickerOption {
  return {
      code: key,
      label: LanguagesEnglish[key],
  }
}
```

Now to map over the enum and generate this array.

```
const options = Object.keys(LanguagesEnglish).map(generateOption);
```

I've been plagued with typescript errors that I find quite confusing. For example, in my `generateOption` function, the `label` property has an error.

```
  Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number | unique symbol | "toString" | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | "substring" | ... 35 more ... | "at"' can't be used to index type 'typeof LanguagesEnglish'.
   No index signature with a parameter of type 'number' was found on type 'typeof LanguagesEnglish'. (lsp)
```

This doesn't make sense to me, because I explicitly indicated that key is not a `number | unique symbol | ...`, I indicated that it's a `keyof LanguagesEnglish` in my function definition.

**What's the correct Typescript way to manage mapping back and forth between Enum types?**

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwDIENEHNla7ADOAongDYCWxAFnAN4BQccA5EgKoDKbcAvO3K5qdNgBoW7AF60AEjhh9BbALI4AJlihVE4uABUoWDVRhUIiLBQlMAvkyYwAnmGBwwVAMYBrYFAB5MHNLAUYpLwgNYAAuOD9nCAAzOBc3ZMwcfEISYVFaAG4pCiwAI2AKOOw8AiIyShpC+yKmJORELxDEOCJEfywYYCCugAoEuISMtOAM6uy6vMaASjjPX39hi27mVihgGGQobalWSOiJ4GdJVlYS8srMmpz6kUaAbQSAXWu4OyKHJiRRDEeAQYJbYhhEZSAKlABWwE6ADoEsQRnNarkGnQlnAsJCxpcpq4ZikMc9Fji3p8mEskagsGARr1+oNNpYlkUgA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: That does work! I'm a bit confused as to why. Does typescript really need to be instructed that the keys generated from an object... are the keys generated from that object?

Comment: Do you mean the `as` part? `Object.keys()` returns `string[]`, but the function accepts the exact keys of the enum, thus we get an error without the assertion. If everything is fine, should I proceed with the answer?

Comment: Yes please, that would be great

Comment: Not sure how embedded you are with using this enum, but if you have the option to change I would simply use an object, in TS there much easier to use & consume.  eg. I find `if (language === 'enUS') {`  looks way better than `if(language === LanguagesEnglish.enUS) {..`  etc.   And because that `enUS` bit is code completes & type checks, there is no downside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums are not what you expect them to be. In fact, in runtime, the enums are compilers to an object with the `key: value` and also `value: key`. Due to this and to other points, `keyof SomeEnum` is not what you want:

```
// number | typeof Symbol.iterator | "charAt" | "charCodeAt" | "concat" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "localeCompare" | "match" | "replace" | "search" | "slice" | "split" | ... 36 more ... | "valueOf"
type Case1 = keyof LanguagesEnglish;
```

What you should actually do is to get the keys of the type of the enum:

```
// type Case2 = "enUS" | "zhHant"
type Case2 = keyof typeof LanguagesEnglish;
```

Now, let's update your types:

```
type pickerOption = {
  code: keyof typeof LanguagesEnglish;
  label: LanguagesEnglish;
};
```

```
function generateOption(key: keyof typeof LanguagesEnglish): pickerOption {
  return {
    code: key,
    label: LanguagesEnglish[key],
  };
}
```

Another issue is that `Object.keys()` don't return the exact keys, but `string[]`, which is described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string).

So, unfortunately, we will need to use *assertion* to make the compiler happy:

```
const options = (
  Object.keys(LanguagesEnglish) as (keyof typeof LanguagesEnglish)[]
).map(generateOption);
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwDIENEHNla7ADOAongDYCWxAFnAN4BQccA5EgKoDKbcAvO3K5qdNgBoW7AF60AEjhh9BbALI4AJlihVE4uABUoWDVRhUIiLBQlMAvkyYwAnmGBwwVAMYBrYFAB5MHNLAUYpLwgNYAAuOD9nCAAzOBc3ZMwcfEISYVFaAG4pCiwAI2AKOOw8AiIyShpC+yKmJORELxDEOCJEfywYYCCugAoEuISMtOAM6uy6vMaASjjPX39hi27mVihgGGQobalWSOiJ4GdJVlYS8srMmpz6kUaAbQSAXWu4OyKHJiRRDEeAQYJbYhhEZSAKlABWwE6ADoEsQRnNarkGnQlnAsJCxpcpq4ZikMc9Fji3p8mEskagsGARr1+oNNpYlkUgA)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
// Use your enums for logical inference rather than UI as it won't scale with localization amongst other things
export enum LanguagesEnglish  {
  enUS = 'enUs',
  zhHant = 'zhHant',
};

// Map the specific keys to the values you want to show on run time (notice it's a const)
const languageLabelMap = {
    [LanguagesEnglish.enUS]: "English",
    [LanguagesEnglish.zhHant]: 'Mandarin, Traditional'
} as const; // notice the const keyword to hard-code the actual values and not their inferred types

type PickerOption = {
  code: LanguagesEnglish,
  // get the languageLabelMap type and map to its values
  label: typeof languageLabelMap[LanguagesEnglish],
};


function generateOption(key: LanguagesEnglish): PickerOption {
  return {
      code: key,
      label: languageLabelMap[key],
  }
}

// map will pass on 3 parameters into its callback, you're only accepting one:
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
// Cast your language string back into LanguageEnglish as keys are automatically casted into strings
const options = Object.keys(LanguagesEnglish).map(language => generateOption(language as LanguagesEnglish));
```

Here's a tsp [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=109&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEFUGcFNQTwPYFcBOpoDskFtKgGYJoA2CA5gJYDGAhsaBRvtCplbCjQC4AWLovGhggBJUDTwUuoAO4IMAcmmRaxWDKk9QpVRQBe3CvPHZ5ZSNIS9%20vRuYBQ0AB4AHItMw5QAGSFkkNGTQkACiGGTEFJBaoADe9qDoGOAAyqAAvKAKmFAKADQJoHo8ABJC0pkKxWUYXPn2AL4A3Pb2IKAAsjQuAnygkC7QVBT41KAA1tBweFwIvbAAbnRIwfDIsuUCc9EIMqDGKEjCXBTYsAAUGFbUsFIKeDSgVPIWAJT2zxgW2n4BQb4AI2gxC6PUy8USiQA2r5wn9gmEIlEeAA6HIpAC6AC5QAAiRGRaK4gqQ0Aw36BBHhQmo6rlbFZLoYAAmNBQjDyoAAKpxmVIjBg6ApGuI8J8LE1QO0rid2PMni9pJM4HIUMytqAeGzmQBaZ7M2DWcRULgBehLYgrB4s0Ay%20YUNCMZgoVjqrhwQaQVruwagAAK1EmKAA8i4TsZwYV9dAcbD-JTQtTkSSpWAgtIjcQKf8aECQd0BB7YEJ1dgC7MGFw8BarYUs3mcT7oAh8D84ZTAcDQeT20FE0johiCs1WvZ8EcTQLQEEMCxuNBQ%20GMOdlbHs1SBzxXjiA1Qg4upxDQKxTShhEfSdGccqU6T68CcVne9BO-mXFDlUPCg1Gq12mWeg0Yh6BcCQ8GMABmUBQM4M4uBYSRajmKQxToYgARoPdOUQJAFFYfYMGIOBjXYMM7AImM2jAHguC4FxICxEADQWYEEEGFAUVMPQKGAmgUSIMhgEwHVUmAZkECoSBgAAdWgAFgAAKRoJYUiodkw2AAAlaBnTYaBgAAcVIDDiAAfWDAEACshirYAAEEXRoOBgAAqjQAAYQkaQcJIdd%20i4dlwlADC9wYJCfHXAlkVFCYpgefCaCQWYy1lNDiNoCxoHVRgKwsQKHHFSwyJeDJQAs6yTRRZVIHOON4X7GlXk47pzifeMggyAA%20adMDneCD3kVq-IkCLnwa5FXleJogA)