# Set react hook form erros dynamically

Tags: typescript, react-hook-form

I get some `errors` after validating a `react-hook-form` on submit:

```js
{
  "companyName": "Error for companyName",
  "addressLine": "Error for addressLine"
}
```

Now I want to call `setError` if the property in `errors` matches a `field` of the form:

```
Object.keys(errors).forEach((key) => {
  if (fields.some((field) => field === key)) {
    setError(key, {
      type: 'custom',
      message: errors[key]
    })
  }
})
```

The code works but I get a compiler error in the `setError` call

```
TS2345: Argument of type  string  is not assignable to parameter of type
"companyName" | "addressLine"
```

I tried this but it didn't work either:

```
type Unionize<T extends object> = {
  [k in keyof T]: k
}

type Props = Unionize<{ companyName: string; addressLine: string}>
```

And then annotate `key` to be of type `Props`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because [`Object.keys` returns a `string[]` in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52856496/25507). Try adding an explicit cast. (You can probably also switch from [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).)

```
Object.keys(errors).forEach((k) => {
  const key = k as keyof typeof errors;
  if (fields.includes(key)) {
    setError(key, {
      type: 'custom',
      message: errors[key]
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, not exactly but this did the trick: `const key = k as keyof { companyName: string; addressLine: string}`

Comment: Of course, I introduced a type for that to make it more usable.