# correct way to represent any object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to create a function to avoid this:

```js
Object.keys(object)
  .map((key) => key as keyof typeof object) // appease ts
  .some((key) => ... // do something with object[key] without ts complaining about it...),
```

all these options seems to work fine:

```js
function keys<Key extends string | symbol | number, O extends Record<Key, unknown>>
  (object: O) { // OK

// function keys<O extends Object>(object: O) { // OK

// function keys<O extends {}>(object: O) { // OK

// function keys<O extends object>(object: O) { // OK
  return Object.keys(object) as Array<keyof O>
}
```

In [this article](https://www.typescripttutorial.net/typescript-tutorial/typescript-object-type/) I found the following explanation:

- The TypeScript object type represents any value that is not a primitive value.
- The Object type, however, describes functionality that is available on all objects.
- The empty type {} refers to an object that has no property on its own.

It seems to me like the first option (`O extends Record<Key, unknown>`) is more accurate, but on the other hand `Object.keys` is types like this in Typescript: `(method) ObjectConstructor.keys(o: {}): string[]`

So I'd like to know the differences and which one is better for representing any object

Comment: [You really shouldn't do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string). There's a good reason `Object.keys` returns `string[]` and not `Array<keyof typeof  whatever>`. It is not type-safe to do what you are doing, and it is disingenuous to callers of your `keys` function to pretend it is.

Comment: As for your *actual* question, this might be handy: https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/tq3m4f/the_difference_between_object_and_recordstring/

Comment: Thanks a lot @jared-smith for the link, if you post it as an answer I'll be glad to accept it as correct

Comment: Done, glad it helps. Frankly the myriad object-ish types is one of my least favorite things about TS, I have to look at the chart every time I want to e.g. constrain a generic properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You really shouldn't try to make a generic version of `Object.keys`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52856496/typescript-object-keys-return-string). There's a good reason `Object.keys` returns `string[]` and not `Array<keyof typeof  whatever>`: the keys of an object may be altered at runtime, and because TS is structurally typed there can *always* be extra keys in the object beyond it's specified type, and those "extra" keys could point to anything.

It is not type-safe to do what you are doing, and it is disingenuous to callers of your keys function to pretend it is. Somebody might call your function, iterate through the array, pull object properties that per the type definition should be values of a certain type, and surprise! get blown up runtime. Probably in production, because [some random guy named Murphy hates you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law).

But in terms of your actual question, check out this [content from reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/tq3m4f/the_difference_between_object_and_recordstring/):

### The difference between {}, object and Record<string, unknown> explained

| Value is assignable to | {} | object | Record<string, unknown> |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "string" | Yes | No | No |
| true | Yes | No | No |
| 42 | Yes | No | No |
| 42n | Yes | No | No |
| Symbol() | Yes | No | No |
| null | No | No | No |
| undefined | No | No | No |
| () => {} | Yes | Yes | No |
| [1, 2] | Yes | Yes | No |
| [] | Yes | Yes | No |
| {foo: "bar"} | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| {} | Yes | Yes | Yes |

In essence:

You can assign anything to {}, except for null and undefined.

You can assign anything that's not a primitive to object. Primitives are strings, booleans, numbers, big integers, symbols, null and undefined.

You can only assign objects to Record<string, unknown>.

Here's a [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/PTAEE0HsFdQYwIYDtQIM5oJYHMXIJ4AuAFpktqIZKAAYDeAvjQDSgBUApgB5wcAOhNqABmkAE60k0ADbSaqJABNa0JR2FkOimgDoAsACg4kJGkKoAXKACCYsQnwAeRgD5QAXlABtQ6D+gAIjMxMmwA5l9-QjFoDgiDf1AAFgAmeMTUpHT-AGV8AFsAI0hpAAoASmy-LwBGVhSAXSrvJsi-OlFIKwDChDEAhmbGZoqPN2HDNtApWWbVRXVNRXiGgG5JgxAIGHhkVAwcPCQiUnJKYgRCAHI0diRIcwRQPhD8zEJMADcOISpaSEKACsOHBCLpDFsAAqvd5fDi3PocUDBUJoVjFEocZBo6bQIocMQ4wo4UBkQgcbAEnFoArFaQ4mgzOQKZQ0eaLJBacFGExmUCFKy2exOAHA0FuTw+BL+Wr1VrS6ryxIdSBdQK9fqDKYTBWgUbucZa3VTILRULhKbRWLNVI2lJZKZ5IolCrNJlzNQaTnLQxrDZbKCwRAoEzSfD7LC4diikGENC-ag0ABKIPEikcKPIrFUAGt7gB3JAubnGUzmOCCuwORwp4xidOZ7DZpB5yCFlwS7zazrdDUDIZGxImxsW3VWuJTW2T+3NJ1011Td1TdlerTNWWgRrrpX+fWGlarIA) demonstrating the table above.

---

In conclusion, trying to type out tables in markdown sucks. At least when I do it in HTML the LSP autocompletes it for me. TIL.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply, how would you handle the aforementioned case in a type safe manner?

Comment: @opensas there's no safe way to do it generally: when you're using runtime reflection (like Object.keys) there's no way to avoid runtime checks, for the same reason the result of a fetch or JSON.parse isn't generic and you should always verify. If you want to get the keys of a *specific* object known at compile-time (rather than have it work for any arbitrary object) you can do it with the keys as an array `const keys: (keyof typeof obj)[] = [...]`,

Comment: [see this here for an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCBGArGBeGBvAUDGBDAXDAMwA02M8hA5ABYCWVmAvpqJLANYCmAnhIQApuPEADMYUHgAcuYuEgCUAbQC6qGEqq4qJGFXhUVrcNBgBbXFJkATdcIgA6C1IFCFqAHzzESjivcA9AEwoGZSdAA2XABOeBERIADuEJhAA) note that the compiler does not check for completeness here, i.e. that *all* the keys of `obj` are in the array.

Comment: Also just to be clear I'm no purist: if you want to call Object.keys and yolo-cast the result because you either don't care about this particular use or know it's safe for reasons the compiler can't prove go for it. My objection was mostly about making promises you can't keep to consumers of your API. Another option would be to use a schema validator like Joi or [Zod](https://zod.dev/)

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. Issuing a `const keys: (keyof typeof obj)[] = [...]` isn't the same thing I'm doing with my keys function? I'm forcing the compiler to handle keys as an `Array<keyof typeof obj>`???

Comment: @opensas no it's different, that's an *annotation* (which the compiler verifies), not a *cast* (which is you the programmer telling the compiler "let me treat this thing as this type you can't prove). The array and object in my example are *compile time constants*, not a dynamic objects whose contents are only known at runtime. The compiler won't let you put some thing in the array that isn't a key of the object. But it only works for things known at compile time, which is why you can't make a safe `keys` function that works with arbitrary objects.